# Why can't I change directories using "cd" in a script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a small script to change the current directory to my project directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/tree/projects/java
```

I saved this file as proj, added execute permission with `chmod`, and copied it to `/usr/bin`. When I call it by:
`proj`, it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cross site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip#176788

Comment: In future you can always try test it with `pwd` on last line. So before script finish then you can check is it working or not..

Comment: @lesmana how is that a duplicate?

Comment: @aland Because OP does **not** in fact run the script, that's why the working dir doesn't change for him. `cd` command works well inside of scripts, try for  yourself.

Comment: [Why is cd not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/44425), [where is `cd` located?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116955/44425)

Comment: `xdotool type --clearmodifiers 'cd ~/projects/java' && xdotool key KP_Enter`

Comment: Fundamentally this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script

Comment: cross-site duplicates: [why cd function in script doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233340/44425), [Why can't I use cd in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441117/44425), [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/481715/253474)

Answer (score 697, accepted):

Shell scripts are run inside a subshell, and each subshell has its own concept of what the current directory is. The `cd` succeeds, but as soon as the subshell exits, you're back in the interactive shell and nothing ever changed there.

One way to get around this is to use an alias instead:

```
alias proj="cd /home/tree/projects/java"
```

Comment: Aliases aren't so flexible to manage or change. In case of many 'cd's, scripts could be better.

Comment: Functions are more flexible than aliases, so that's where you'd look next when aliases aren't enough.

Comment: I think this discussion gets pointless. "There are zillions ways to make things in Perl" (tm)

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation, coupled with a helpful alternative!

Comment: Is it worth noting that on MS-DOS, the behaviour of scripts was that a called script could change the directory (and even drive) of the calling command shell?  And that Unix does not have this defect?

Comment: Jonathan: while that's true, it's not really related to the question. Answers on SO would get twice as long if they had to each list the corresponding deficiencies in MS-DOS!

Comment: s/defect/side effect/; s/worth noting/not &/

Comment: @FedericoA.Ramponi or in ~/.bash_aliases

Comment: Another way to get around it is to source the script file: `. my-script` or `source my-script`.

Answer (score 560):

You're doing nothing wrong!  You've changed the directory, but only within the subshell that runs the script.

You can run the script in your current process with the "dot" command:

```
. proj
```

But I'd prefer Greg's suggestion to use an alias in this simple case.

Comment: `.` is also spelled `source`, choose whichever you find more memorable.

Comment: @Ephemient: Good pointsource That explains why it workssource Also proves that laziness-not necessity-is often the mother of inventionsource

Comment: @ephemient: note that source is used in C shell and Bash; it is not supported in POSIX or Korn shells, nor in classic Bourne shell.

Comment: "source" is used in Z-shell

Comment: @AdamLiss It works great, but there is one drawback - somehow source/dot command disables possibility to auto-complete name of the script/command with TAB key. It is still possible to add arguments/input with TAB key, but unfortunately name of the command needs to be input directly. Do you know how to make TAB key work in this case?

Comment: @Rafal I tested this on my system (from a PuTTY terminal).  I was able to tab complete the name of the command with no problem for both dot and 'source'.  Might be your environment?

Comment: @Stuart You are right. I just tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 and tab completion works great. It must have been an issue with Ubuntu 13.10 back in January 2014 or maybe my configuration. Thanks for info.

Comment: Another option is to combine both approaches, if you want a complex behaviour write it in an executalbe called `myscript`, and in `.bashrc` write `alias myscript=". myscript"`

Comment: @J27avier: Wow, 15 years later, and still relevant! Your suggestion is super useful, and I've been using an embellished version of it for years. I keep "simple"  aliases in my `.bash_aliases` file, which ends with the line `[[ ! -f ~/.bash_functions ]] || . ~/.bash_functions`. I keep more complex items in that second file, e.g., `ff() { dir="$1"; name="$2"; shift 2; find "$dir" -name "$name" -type f | xargs grep "$@"; }`. And, of course, `alias al='vi ~/.bash_aliases && . ~/.bash_aliases'` lets me edit the aliases and have them take immediate effect.

Answer (score 234):

The `cd` in your script technically *worked* as it changed the directory of the shell that ran the script, but that was a separate process forked from your interactive shell.

A Posix-compatible way to solve this problem is to define a *shell procedure* rather than a shell-invoked *command script*.

```
jhome () {
  cd /home/tree/projects/java
}
```

You can just type this in or put it in one of the various shell startup files.

Comment: I agree, this is the best answer, bumped. Also, alias may be appropriate in some situations but if he's trying to use cd in a script and wanted to add anything else to it an alias would be useless.

Comment: This looks like a solution! And I'm trying to implement it, but it's not performing :( here's my script: 

#!/bin/bash
jhome() {
  echo "please"
  cd /home
  echo "work"
}
jhome

Comment: @GantMan, you should add this in a"shell startup files", like ~/.bashrc

Comment: If it's in a file you need to use `.   filename` or `source filename` so that the current shell sees it, rather than the subshell that ran the command. Or take Jackie's advice and put it in something like `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You can also use an argument (or two...), ie: `jhome(){ cd /home/tree/projects/$1; }`

Comment: This should be the right way, this makes it possible to use special characters, like "-" for example.

Comment: Perfect, just solved my problem flawlessly. This should be marked has the right answer.

Answer (score 180):

The `cd` is done within the script's shell. When the script ends, that shell exits, and then you are left in the directory you were. "Source" the script, don't run it. Instead of:

```
./myscript.sh
```

do

```
. ./myscript.sh
```

(Notice the dot and space before the script name.)

Comment: This is cool, and probably good to know.  What does the latter do exactly though (how does it work)?  This is probably the best solution on this thread.

Comment: fwiw, in the comments section of Adam Liss' answer, ephemient answers the question of what the '.' is. It is the same thing as `source`

Comment: Be careful, "source" is a bashism. i.e. dash (Debian default for /bin/sh) does not support it, while "." works as expected.

Comment: Great answer! also if `myscript.sh` is in a directory included in $PATH, you can source it from anywhere without specifying the full path.

Comment: This worked for me the best. This solution is the simplest (+1).

Answer (score 103):

#### To make a bash script that will cd to a select directory :

Create the script file

```
#!/bin/sh
# file : /scripts/cdjava
#
cd /home/askgelal/projects/java
```

Then create an alias in your startup file.

```
#!/bin/sh
# file /scripts/mastercode.sh
#
alias cdjava='. /scripts/cdjava'
```

---

- I created a startup file where I dump all my aliases and custom functions.

  Then I source this file into my .bashrc to have it set on each boot.

For example, create a master aliases/functions file: **/scripts/mastercode.sh**
*(Put the alias in this file.)*

Then at the end of your **.bashrc** file:

```
source /scripts/mastercode.sh
```

---

Now its easy to cd to your java directory, just type cdjava and you are there.

Comment: the file `mastercode.sh` doesn't need the shabang (`#!/bin/sh`), since it is not (and can not be) executed in a subshell. But at the same time, you do need to document the shell "flavor" of this file; e.g., ksh or bash (or (t)csh/zsh,etc), and it's almost certainly not actually `sh`.  I usually add a comment (but not the shebang) to communicate this; e.g., _"this file is meant to be sourced (from bash), not run as a shell script."_

Comment: Another tip (for bash): if you use variables in your script, then as the script is being `source`d (via the `alias`), those variables will leak into your shell environment. To avoid that, do all the work of the script in a function, and just call it at the end of the script. Within the function, declare any variables `local`.

Comment: in ubuntu just create ~/.bash_aliases (if it doesn't exist already). Then just add your aliases there, restart the terminal and your done.

Answer (score 58):

You can use `.` to execute a script in the current shell environment:

```
. script_name
```

or alternatively, its more readable but shell specific alias `source`:

```
source script_name
```

This avoids the subshell, and allows any variables or builtins (including `cd`) to affect the current shell instead.

Answer (score 41):

## Use `exec bash` at the end

> A bash script operates on its current environment or on that of its
> children, but never on its parent environment.

However, this question often gets asked because one wants **to be left at a (new) bash prompt in a certain directory after execution** of a bash script from within another directory.

If this is the case, simply **execute a child bash instance** at the end of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/tree/projects/java
echo -e '\nHit [Ctrl]+[D] to exit this child shell.'
exec bash
```

To return to the previous, parental `bash` instance, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

### Update

At least with newer versions of `bash`, the `exec` on the last line is no longer required. Furthermore, the script could be made to work with whatever preferred shell by using the `$SHELL` environment variable. This then gives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd desired/directory
echo -e '\nHit [Ctrl]+[D] to exit this child shell.'
$SHELL
```

Comment: This creates a new subshell.  When you type `exit` you will return to the shell where you ran this script.

Comment: When script was called several times seems it creates nested shells and I need to type 'exit' a lot of times. Could this be solved somehow?

Comment: See the other answers: use an alias, use "pushd/popd/dirs", or use "source"

Comment: @Acumenus You are absolutely right. The `exec` was required with older versions of `bash` and possibly other shells. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: After running `exec bash` can I remain in the script and continue to run another commands?

Comment: @alper Yes, certainly. More commands can be executed in the new child `bash` instance. To return to the previous, parental `bash` instance, use [Ctrl]+[D].

Comment: This would work for me if it wasn't for the fact I rely on the shell history to autocomplete commands! Thanks for posting though.

Answer (score 40):

Jeremy Ruten's idea of using a symlink triggered a thought that hasn't crossed any other answer.  Use:

```
CDPATH=:$HOME/projects
```

The leading colon is important; it means that if there is a directory 'dir' in the current directory, then '`cd dir`' will change to that, rather than hopping off somewhere else.  With the value set as shown, you can do:

```
cd java
```

and, if there is no sub-directory called java in the current directory, then it will take you directly to $HOME/projects/java - no aliases, no scripts, no dubious execs or dot commands.

My $HOME is /Users/jleffler; my $CDPATH is:

```
:/Users/jleffler:/Users/jleffler/mail:/Users/jleffler/src:/Users/jleffler/src/perl:/Users/jleffler/src/sqltools:/Users/jleffler/lib:/Users/jleffler/doc:/Users/jleffler/work
```

Answer (score 28):

I got my code to work by using`. <your file name>`

`./<your file name>` dose not work because it doesn't change your directory in the terminal it just changes the directory specific to that script.

Here is my program

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Taking you to eclipse's workspace."
cd /Developer/Java/workspace
```

Here is my terminal

```
nova:~ Kael$ 
nova:~ Kael$ . workspace.sh
Taking you to eclipe's workspace.
nova:workspace Kael$
```

Comment: What's the difference between `. something` and `./something`?? This answer worked for me and I don't understand why.

Comment: `. something` allows you to run the script from any location, `./something` requires you to be in the directory the file is stored in.

Comment: @Dracorat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-in-a-linux-shell-between-source-and-sh

Comment: Can you put the dot in the shebang line? `#!. /bin/bash`?

Answer (score 21):

simply run:

```
cd /home/xxx/yyy && command_you_want
```

Answer (score 13):

When you fire a shell script, it runs a *new* instance of that shell (`/bin/bash`).  Thus, your script just fires up a shell, changes the directory and exits.  Put another way, `cd` (and other such commands) within a shell script do not affect nor have access to the shell from which they were launched.

Answer (score 12):

You can do following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your/project/directory
# start another shell and replacing the current
exec /bin/bash
```

EDIT: This could be 'dotted' as well, to prevent creation of subsequent shells.

Example:

```
. ./previous_script  (with or without the first line)
```

Comment: That gets rather messy after a few runs.. You will have to `exit` (or ctrl+d) several times to exit the shell, for example.. An alias is so much cleaner (even if the shell command outputs a directory, and it cd's to the output - alias something="cd `getnewdirectory.sh`")

Comment: Note the 'exec'. It makes replace of old shell.

Comment: The exec only replaces the sub-shell that was running the cd command, not the shell that ran the script.  Had you dotted the script, then you'd be correct.

Comment: Make it 'dotted' - no problem. I just proposed solution. It doesn't depend on how you launch this.

Comment: Hehe, I think it's better just to 'dot' one-line script with only cd command :) I'll keep my answer anyway... That will be correct stupid answer to incorrect stupid question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script is what i would propose for interactive usage to launch a dev env.

Comment: exec /bin/bash did what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me to address a loong pending problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `exec zsh` for zsh

Answer (score 12):

On my particular case i needed too many times to change for the same directory. 
So on my .bashrc (I use ubuntu) i've added the

1 -

> $ nano ~./bashrc

```
 function switchp
 {
    cd /home/tree/projects/$1
 }
```

2-

> $ source ~/.bashrc

3 -

> $ switchp java

Directly it will do: cd /home/tree/projects/java

Hope that helps!

Comment: @W.M. You can eventually do "$ switchp" without any parameter to go directly to the project tree

Comment: @workdreamer The function approach you described above solved a little trouble here in going into sub-folders which have same parent folder at my system. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can combine Adam & Greg's alias and dot approaches to make something that can be more dynamic—

```
alias project=". project"
```

Now running the project alias will execute the project script in the current shell as opposed to the subshell.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to maintain all my script and just call it from bash and maintain current session - this is the PERFECT answer.

Answer (score 7):

It only changes the directory for the script itself, while your current directory stays the same.

You might want to use a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) instead. It allows you to make a "shortcut" to a file or directory, so you'd only have to type something like `cd my-project`.

Comment: Having that symlink in every directory would be a nuisance.  It would be possible to put the symlink in $HOME and then do 'cd ~/my-project'.  Frankly, though, it is simpler to use CDPATH.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine an alias and a script,

```
alias proj="cd \`/usr/bin/proj !*\`"
```

provided that the script echos the destination path.  Note that those are backticks surrounding the script name.

For example, your script could be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo /home/askgelal/projects/java/$1
```

The advantage with this technique is that the script could take any number of command line parameters and emit different destinations calculated by possibly complex logic.

Comment: why? you could just use: `proj() { cd "/home/user/projects/java/$1"; }` => `proj "foo"` (or, `proj "foo bar"` <= in case you have spaces)... or even (for example): `proj() { cd "/home/user/projects/java/$1"; shift; for d; do cd "$d"; done; }` => `proj a b c` => does a `cd` into `/home/user/projects/java/a/b/c`

Answer (score 6):

to navigate directories quicky, there's $CDPATH, cdargs, and ways to generate aliases automatically

http://jackndempsey.blogspot.com/2008/07/cdargs.html

http://muness.blogspot.com/2008/06/lazy-bash-cd-aliaes.html

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5827311.html

Answer (score 5):

In your ~/.bash_profile file. add the next function

```
move_me() {
    cd ~/path/to/dest
}
```

Restart terminal and you can type

```
move_me
```

and you will be moved to the destination folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the operator && :

cd myDirectory && ls

Comment: Downvote: This does not attempt to answer the actual question here.  You can run two commands at the prompt (with `&&` if you want the second to be conditional on the first, or just with `;` or newline between them) but putting this in a script will take you back to "why doesn't the parent shell use the new directory when the `cd` was actually successful?"

Answer (score 3):

While sourcing the script you want to run is one solution, you should be aware that this script then can directly modify the environment of your current shell. Also it is not possible to pass arguments anymore.

Another way to do, is to implement your script as a function in bash.

```
function cdbm() {
  cd whereever_you_want_to_go
  echo "Arguments to the functions were $1, $2, ..."
}
```

This technique is used by autojump: http://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki to provide you with learning shell directory bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function like below in your `.bash_profile` and it will work smoothly.

The following function takes an optional parameter which is a project.
For example, you can just run

```
cdproj
```

or

```
cdproj project_name
```

Here is the function definition.

```
cdproj(){
    dir=/Users/yourname/projects
    if [ "$1" ]; then
      cd "${dir}/${1}"
    else
      cd "${dir}"
    fi
}
```

Dont forget to source your `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want. Change to the directory of interest (from within the script), and then spawn a new bash shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

# saved as mov_dir.sh
cd ~/mt/v3/rt_linux-rt-tools/
bash
```

If you run this, it will take you to the directory of interest and when you exit it it will bring you back to the original place.

```
root@intel-corei7-64:~# ./mov_dir.sh

root@intel-corei7-64:~/mt/v3/rt_linux-rt-tools# exit
root@intel-corei7-64:~#
```

This will even take you to back to your original directory when you exit (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

Comment: Spawning a new bash will mean you lose your history and it will start fresh.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

create a file called case

paste the following in the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/"$1"
```

save it and then:

```
chmod +x case
```

I also created an alias in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias disk='cd /home/; . case'
```

now when I type:

```
case 12345
```

essentially I am typing:

```
cd /home/12345
```

You can type any folder after 'case':

```
case 12

case 15

case 17
```

which is like typing:

```
cd /home/12

cd /home/15

cd /home/17
```

respectively

In my case the path is much longer - these guys summed it up with the ~ info earlier.

Comment: The `cd` in the alias is superfluous and inelegant; the alias should simply ’. ~/case` instead. Also `case` is a reserved keyword, so a rather poor choice for a name.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the other answers, you have changed the directory, but only within the **sub-shell that runs the script**. this does not impact the parent shell.

One solution is to use **bash functions** instead of a bash script (`sh`); by placing your bash script code into a function. That makes the function available as a command and then, this will be executed without a child process and thus any `cd` command will impact the caller shell.

**Bash functions :**

One feature of the bash profile is to store custom functions that can be run in the terminal or in bash scripts the same way you run application/commands this also could be used as a shortcut for long commands.

To make your function efficient system widely you will need to copy your function at the end of several files

```
/home/user/.bashrc
/home/user/.bash_profile
/root/.bashrc
/root/.bash_profile
```

You can `sudo kwrite /home/user/.bashrc /home/user/.bash_profile /root/.bashrc  /root/.bash_profile` to edit/create those files quickly

**Howto :**

Copy your bash script code inside a new function at the end of your bash's profile file and restart your terminal, you can then run `cdd` or whatever the function you wrote.

**Script Example**

Making shortcut to `cd ..` with `cdd`

```
cdd() {
  cd ..
}
```

ls shortcut

```
ll() {
  ls -l -h
}
```

ls shortcut

```
lll() {
  ls -l -h -a
}
```

Comment: This really works. I am surprised it has not been upvoted as much as it would deserve.

Comment: @EerikSvenPuudist :) it was a late answer on a popular post I guess that reader don't reach it, thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/) as your shell, the best solution is to create a function. As an example, given the original question, you could copy the 4 lines below and paste them into your fish command line:

```
function proj
   cd /home/tree/projects/java
end
funcsave proj
```

This will create the function and save it for use later. If your project changes, just repeat the process using the new path.

If you prefer, you can manually add the function file by doing the following:

```
nano ~/.config/fish/functions/proj.fish
```

and enter the text:

```
function proj
   cd /home/tree/projects/java
end
```

and finally press ctrl+x to exit and y followed by return to save your changes.

(*NOTE: the first method of using funcsave creates the proj.fish file for you*).

Answer (score 0):

You need no script, only set the correct option and create an environment variable.

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
```

in your `~/.bashrc` allows to `cd` to the content of environment variables.

Create such an environment variable:

```
export myjava="/home/tree/projects/java"
```

and you can use:

```
cd myjava
```

[Other alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/a/481733/4246).

Answer (score 0):

Note the discussion [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process/)

It contains some hackish answers, e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375174/755804 (changing the parent process directory via gdb, don't do this) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985735/755804 (the command `tailcd` that injects *cd dirname* to the input stream of the parent process; well, ideally it should be a part of bash rather than a hack)

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but I am really surprised I don't see this trick here

Instead of using **cd** you can use

```
export PWD=the/path/you/want
```

No need to create subshells or use aliases.

Note that it is your responsibility to make sure the/path/you/want exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have to work in tcsh, and I know this is not an elegant solution, but for example, if I had to change folders to a path where one word is different, the whole thing can be done in the alias

```
a alias_name 'set a = `pwd`; set b = `echo $a | replace "Trees" "Tests"` ; cd $b'
```

If the path is always fixed, the just

```
a alias_name2 'cd path/you/always/need'
```

should work
In the line above, the new folder path is set

Answer (score 0):

This combines the [answer by Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36768357/) with an [unrelated answer by David](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352430/). It changes the directory, and then instead of forcing a bash shell, it **launches the user's default shell**. It however requires both `getent` and `/etc/passwd` to detect the default shell.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd desired/directory
USER_SHELL=$(getent passwd <USER> | cut -d : -f 7)
$USER_SHELL
```

Of course this still has the same deficiency of creating a nested shell.

Answer (score 0):

instead of excute a script file and cd to the certain folder,

we can make it by:

- `source` or `.` certain shell script
- `alias` the cd command
- define a function ant cd to folder

examples:

```sh
. script
# or
source script
```

```sh
alias ghqc='cd $(ghq root)/$(ghq list | fzf)'
```

```sh
ghqc() {
  cd $(ghq root)/$1
}
```

Comment: Is this not already covered by existing answers?

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple bash script called p to manage directory changing on
[github.com/godzilla/bash-stuff](https://github.com/godzilla/bash-stuff)
just put the script in your local bin directory (/usr/local/bin)
 
and put

```
alias p='. p'
```

in your .bashrc

Comment: what does this do?  it looks like it would recursively run itself, although I'm sure if you've run it before it doesn't ;)

Answer (score -3):

You can execute some lines in the same subshell if you end lines with backslash.

```
cd somedir; \
pwd
```