# Run bash script as source without source command

Tags: bash, dot-source

Is there any way to mark a script to be "run as source" so you don't have to add the `source` or "." command to it every time? i.e., if I write a script called "sup", I'd like to call it as

```
sup Argument
```

rather than

```
source sup Argument
```

or

```
. sup Argument
```

Basically, I'm trying to use `cd` within a script.

Comment: please clarify.  the issue of making the script exectuable and the issue of using "cd" within a script are not the same thing.

Comment: "Is there any way to mark a script to be "run as source" so you don't have to add the source or "." command to it every time?"

Comment: You have two different issues here, which is why I asked for clarification.  You can make scripts executable, and then you won't need "." or "source", but they won't be able to modify the callers environment (the shell you execute from).  So cd makes no change to caller.  Different problems.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Bash forks and starts a subshell way before it or your kernel even considers what it's supposed to do in there.  It's not something you can "undo".  So no, it's impossible.

Thankfully.

Look into `bash` functions instead:

```
sup() {
    ...
}
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 25):

When you are running a shell, there are two ways to invoke a shell script:

- **Executing** a script spawns a new process inside which the script is running. This is done by typing the script name, if it is made executable and starts with a

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  line, or directly invoking

  ```
  /bin/bash mycmd.sh
  ```
- **Sourcing** a script runs it inside its parent shell (i.e. the one you are typing commands into). This is done by typing

  ```
  source mycmd.sh
  ```

  or

  ```
  . mycmd.sh
  ```

So the cd inside a shell script that isn't sourced is *never* going to propagate to its parent shell, as this would violate process isolation.

If the *cd* is all you are interested about, you can get rid of the script by using cd "shortcuts"... Take a look into the bash doc, at the CDPATH env var.

Otherwise, you can use an alias to be able to type a single command, instead of source or .:

```
alias mycmd="source mycmd.sh"
```

Comment: I did modify my CDPATH, but it still doesn't seem to work when the script is executing in its "own" shell

Comment: Yes, of course, because the change doesn't get propagated to the parent shell, the one that you are using. My remark was more about a way to get rid of the script altogether.

Comment: that's perfect! I never even thought to just alias it

Answer (score 10):

Create an alias for it:

```
alias sup=". ~/bin/sup"
```

Or along those lines.

See also: [Why doesn't cd work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script/255526)

---

Answering comment by counter-example: experimentation with Korn Shell on Solaris 10 shows that I can do:

```
$ pwd
/work1/jleffler
$ echo "cd /work5/atria" > $HOME/bin/yyy
$ alias yyy=". ~/bin/yyy"
$ yyy
$ pwd
/work5/atria
$
```

Experimentation with Bash (3.00.16) on Solaris 10 also shows the same behaviour.

---

Comment: Hmm, alias worked, but still executes in a separate shell so the 'cd' within the script does nothing. Thanks though!

Comment: In that case, probably go with the CDPATH solution in the referenced question?  It's what I use mostly.  What is actually in the script?  Just a 'cd' or a whole lot more stuff?

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to source a script in your current environment if you sub-shell the script at invoke.

However, you can **check that script is sourced** and force the script to terminate if not:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ] ; then
    echo "This script must be sourced. Use \"source <script>\" instead."
    exit
fi
```

The same way, you can **force a script not to be sourced** but to be sub-shelled instead (preserve current shell environment):

```
if [ "$PS1" ] ; then
    echo "This script cannot be sourced. Use \"./<script>\" instead."
    return
fi
```

Both versions are available as gists: see [please source](https://gist.github.com/timlegrand/d67d502be82be7983ff1) and [don't source](https://gist.github.com/timlegrand/a6911f653d5a785b57cd).

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is not ideal -- even if the shell is always bash, sometimes it'll just print `-e` on output, depending on the value of the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags (as the POSIX `echo` spec permits special handling *only* for `-n`, a strictly POSIX-compliant `echo` is not allowed to do anything with `-e` other than print it on output). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: Thanks it was a typo, no use here. Removed.

Comment: I'd print to stderr (i.e. `>&2 echo 'This script must be sourced.'). Otherwise, this is great advice!