# Bash - cd your instance rather than sub process

Tags: bash

So I've created a bash script that takes argument and then (I want it to) cd me into a directory.

It's not quite a case of cd /home/$1 for example, it's a bit more complex.

The problem is (as I knew it would be) it's cding the sub process rather than my instance of bash.

Is there any way to apply it to my open bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: Can you paste the relevant part of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the desired directory, then create a bash alias as follows:

```
alias jump="cd $(myscript.sh)"
```

It's the approach I use for [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki), and it works very well.

Comment: alias go="cd $(/home1/users/joe.borg/scripts/sh/go.sh)"

When I try to source this I get

[joe.borg@box ~]$ source .tcshrc
Illegal variable name.

Comment: Shouldn't this go into your .bashrc instead?

Comment: I wrote the script in bash, but (unfortunately) the box is tcsh be default

Comment: Change your default shell then: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/14368-how-can-i-change-my-default-shell.html

Comment: I know how to do that, but this is on a box at work.  I obviously use bash at home

Comment: Well then if you need to use tcsh, I'd ask again for tcsh instead of bash :) I can't help you with tcsh, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is another option for you

[favorite directory](http://dirb.info/)