# Bash shell script run on UNIX command line does not change the current shell environment

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't “cd” work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

I'm attempting to execute a bash shell script './go_cd' from the UNIX command line in my working directory '/c/My_Objective'. All I expect the script to do is change to a new directory '/c/My_Objective/project'. The script output indicates that the directory has been changed to '/c/My_Objective/project, however when the script completes execution and returns to the current command line, the directory is still at '/c/My_Objective'. Why was the directory not changed?

### Below is the simple Bash shell script that I'm using as a test.

```
#!/bin/bash
## current directory is '/c/My_Objective'
pwd
cd project
## new directory should now be '/c/My_Objective/project'
pwd
```

---

Is there a way to get the commands, ie., 'cd', executing in the new script process get passed back to the original process where I started 'go_cd' script execution?

Winston

Comment: If you're used to DOS, then this is a big change of behaviour, but Unix works as described in the answer and in the x-ref'd question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script : use a subshell ( end your script with exec bash )

Answer (score 6):

Subprocesses don't affect the parent process. If you want your shell script to modify the existing shell, it has to be run by the existing shell, something like:

```
. myscript.sh
```

Comment: Or write it as a shell function rather than a shell script.

Comment: Or if it does only a cd, create an alias in your ~/.bashrc : `alias cdc='cd /c/My_Objective/project'`

Comment: Thnak you, the suggestion of using the equivalent of '.myscript.sh ' works. I try the alias in bashrc later. You'll have been very helpful.