# How to check if it is a directory/file in linux shell

Tags: file, shell, directory

Iam making a program with a fast menu in linux shell.

A option is to edit or to change directory.

I need to see if it is a directory or a file, because i need to use vim for a file and cd for a directory.

Thank you for reading/helping

Comment: Did you check `man test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Input a file: "
IFS= read -r file

if test -f "$file"
then
  echo "$file is a regular file"
elif test -d "$file"
  echo "$file is a directory"
else
  echo "It's something else, like a socket, fifo or device."
fi
```

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script) if you `cd` but still find yourself in the same directory after your script exits.