# Bash decorating "cd" - change directory inside a script

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to have something like this - when I type "go", it would cd to a directory, fire "pwd" and "ls -a".

```
~ $ pwd
/home/ondra
~ $ go sketchbook

/home/ondra/sketchbook
.  ..  libraries

~ $ pwd
/home/ondra/sketchbook
~ $
```

First I tried with alias, it didn't work, now I have this, but it doesn't work either:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
pwd
ls -a
```

It properly prints the info for the target directory, but does not change to it.

Looks like it works only within the script. Any way to do this?

Comment: @Ignacio that is nice, but that doesn't explain how can I do it.

Comment: This other duplicate's accepted answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script

Comment: Did you read the answers?

Comment: Yes, it's all some tricks with alias, I want a real solution

Comment: Besides, if I use alias like "my script.sh && cd", my script won't receive the argument. That's not a solution.

Comment: Function is not a trick but the solution. Your problem is that all commands from your script are run within a new shell. When it ends you come back to the old one and its PWD. Another way is to source commands from the file: source go sketchbook or . go sketchbook. Actually it's described as another answer to the question mentioned above. You can even overwrite `cd` that way.

Comment: Okay, I've achieved what I want by adding that function to .bashrc. Hacky but does the trick.