# How to have terminal remember a directory?

Tags: terminal, directory, cd

I always have to `cd` to a very long line of a path in the terminal.

Is there a way to have terminal remember the path, so that I can just type in for example,

`cd path1`

to get to a very long path `cd /Users/user-name/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah` ?

I don't really want to use `cd -`, cause I may switch between several directories.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can add:

```
alias path1='cd /Users/user-name/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah'
```

to .profile. Then in your terminal you only need to type:

```
path1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask how to add the alias path to the .profile? Sorry for being stupid not knowing this...

Comment: .profile can be found in "/Users/user-name/". You can open it in any text editor and add the line above. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, could you accept the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few directories, you could write aan script for each of them. See this SO answer for example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/874542

Otherwise, maybe a tool like Z could be useful for you?

https://github.com/rupa/z