# Can't change directory in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to change directory in shell script to the one given by the command line argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 755 findfn.sh
dir=$1

while [ -d "${dir}" ]
do
    cd $HOME/"$1"
done
```

I've looked at many other posts and tried:

- `cd "dir"`
- `cd ~/"$1"`
- `cd source "$1"`
- Removing `#!bin/bash`
- Changing `chmod 755` to `chmod 700`, etc

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT
Just tried this

```
alias dirc="cd /home/$1"
    echo $PWD
```

but it still doesnt change directory, it just keeps printing out 
"/home"

Comment: (why do you use for loop?) do you wish you could cd to that dir after you execute the file? but script is running in subshell, after your program exit, it will still be in the original dir

Comment: Yes the reason why I'm using while is because I am going to add in more commands later, after I figure out how to cd first

Comment: you add `echo $PWD` under your `cd` command, and see whether the dir already changed?

Comment: changing present working directory is specific to that process. Check this post, if you really want to change your shell $PWD [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-the-current-directory-from-a-bash-script] (Change the current directory from a Bash script)

Comment: @ian : Do a `pwd` right after the `cd`, for verifying. Of course if `$1` contains a nonsense value, the command might fail, but you would then see an error message. If you want to be on the safe side, you can also check the status code after cd. If `cd` does not work, `$?` is non-zero.

Comment: How many times do you think `while [ -d "${dir}" ]` will execute if `$dir` is never updated? Do you expect to be left in the new directory when the script exits? What is the value of `$PWD` in the parent shell before you execute the child script? What is the rule about a child being able to affect the environment of its parent?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1

while [ -d "${dir}" ]  #it will check if the argument directory is present where script is executed.
do
    cd $HOME/"$1"  
done
```

Let's say `/tmp` contains above script as `a.sh`,
and `/tmp/abc` is present and also `/home/abc` is present,

then you have to run the script like below:

```
$. a.sh abc
```

and it will go to `/home/abc`