# Not able to change directory from bash script despite sourcing

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I have following 2 files:

file cd2vcaa (in path):

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

file test.sh (in current directory):

```
#! /bin/bash
. cd2vcaa
```

From terminal, I am able to change directory with `. cd2vcaa` but not with `./test.sh`

```
~$ cd2vcaa                        <-- no effect
~$ . cd2vcaa                      <-- changes directory
/var/cache/apt/archives$ cd       <-- back to home directory
~$ ./test.sh                      <-- does not change directory though no error - why?
~$
```

Why is `. cd2vcaa` working from terminal but from within another script?
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: `./test.sh` runs in a sub-shell so any source commands affect only the sub-shell and not the parent one.

Comment: How to correct this?

Comment: Depends what you are really trying to achieve. Obviously `. ./test.sh` would do it but that's unlikely to be what you want, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test.sh` runs in a separate shell when you invoke it using `./test.sh`, so although the sourcing inside `test.sh` means that the `cd` command will affect the current directory in the shell in which `test.sh` runs, so for example any commands added at the end of `test.sh` would run with current directory `/var/cache/apt/archives`, it will not affect the parent shell (your login session).

If you invoke the `test.sh` by sourcing it (`. test.sh`), then no sub-shell is launched at either stage, and the directory is changed in your login session.

As discussed in the comments, if the aim is simply to have use of an interactive shell which is `cd`-ed to the specified directory (not necessarily the parent shell), then one option is just to put `bash` at the end of the `test.sh` in order to start an interactive subshell after the `cd` command has been run.  On exit from this subshell, control will return to the login shell, still in its original working directory.

Comment: I want to run `./test.sh` and that should change directory when test.sh ends.

Comment: @rnso That is not going to be possible. If you can provide more detail of _why_ you want to run `./test.sh` and it is not adequate for you to run `. ./test.sh` instead, then maybe someone can suggest a suitable workaround.

Comment: Its simple. I want a script to update my system and then leave me in archives folder at the end. I want to check `.deb` files there so that I can delete them if needed.

Comment: Can using a function help? As in accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-the-current-directory-from-a-bash-script

Comment: Would it meet your requirements if it launched an interactive subshell at the end that was `cd`-ed to the archives folder? You could achieve this by putting just `bash` inside your `test.sh` at the end. Obviously when you exit from this subshell, you will return to the original login shell, not immediately log out completely. If you don't want this, then using a function (or an alias) might be an alternative solution, but you will still have to source something to define the function (although this will only need to be done once, e.g. in your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: Putting `bash` at end of script is a simple and easy solution for my purposes. If you put his in above answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @rnso I've added a final paragraph about it.