# Global environment variables in a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, environment-variables

How to set a global environment variable in a bash script?

If I do stuff like

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bar
```

...or

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=bar
```

...the vars seem to stay in the local context, whereas I'd like to keep using them after the script has finished executing.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Run your script with `.`

```
. myscript.sh
```

This will run the script in the current shell environment.

`export` governs which variables will be available to new processes, so if you say

```
FOO=1
export BAR=2
./runScript.sh
```

then `$BAR` will be available in the environment of `runScript.sh`, but `$FOO` will not.

Comment: Be careful with that first one. Without a slash, it will look in your path: use something like '. ./myscript.sh' if you want to ensure it runs a specific one.

Comment: `source` is an alias for `.`. So you could run `source myscript.sh` instead, if you wanted to be more explicit.

Comment: I am wondering what happens when i run a script with dot and a space. example . myscript

Comment: @cNgamba Ask a new question if you can't find it by reading the other answers on this page and/or googling, but this is a common FAQ; see also e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell

Answer (score 63):

When you *run* a shell script, it's done in a sub-shell so it cannot affect the parent shell's environment. You want to source the script by doing:

```
. ./setfoo.sh
```

This executes it in the context of the *current* shell, not as a *sub* shell.

From the bash man page:

> **.      filename [arguments]**
>   **source filename [arguments]**
>
> Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell
>   environment and return the exit status of the last command executed
>   from filename.
>
> If filename does not contain a slash, file names in PATH are used to
>   find the directory containing filename.
>
> The file searched for in PATH need not be executable. When bash is not
>   in POSIX mode, the current directory is searched if no file is found
>   in PATH.
>
> If the sourcepath option to the shopt builtin command is turned off,
>   the PATH is not searched.
>
> If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters
>   when filename is  executed.
>
> Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged. The return status
>   is the status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no
>   commands are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot
>   be read.

Comment: Interesting - I've not seen that syntax before. Is this equivalent to source ./setfoo.sh?

Comment: It's the same, just faster to type (and more compatible on older systems - ksh has no source command but it does have '.').

Answer (score 13):

`source myscript.sh` is also feasible.

Description for linux command `source`:

```
source is a Unix command that evaluates the file following the command, 
as a list of commands, executed in the current context
```

Comment: Maybe just a tad more detail here. How about a very brief description of what `source` does?

Comment: @PhillipCloud type `man source` in the terminal and you'll get what you want.

Comment: I'm familiar with `source`. Maybe the OP isn't.

Comment: @PhillipCloud I would like some more detail, myself. If you want to edit the answer, you can definitely do that. Help the cause and all that... Thx!

Comment: `man source` may well return `No manual entry for source`. Try `help source` instead. This is because `source` is a command within the `bash` command language interpreter, so it has no man page of its own. Type `help` for all commands defined **internally** by the shell.

Comment: While Bash is the default shell on many Linux platforms, and the question asks about Bash, the question is relevant for other shells besides Bash. At the very least, this answer should mention that this solution is not portable to many other shells.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=bar
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bar
export FOO
```

*man export:*

The shell shall give the export attribute to the variables corresponding to the specified names, which shall cause them to be in the environment of subsequently executed commands. If the name of a variable is followed by = word, then the value of that variable shall be set to word.

Comment: Please, to every beginner in shell scripting: note there isn't any blank between the envvar name, '=' character and the value itself; this wouldn't work: `export FOO = /mydir/bar`

Answer (score 0):

A common design is to have your script output a result, and require the cooperation of the caller. Then you can say, for example,

```
eval "$(yourscript)"
```

or perhaps less dangerously

```
cd "$(yourscript)"
```

This extends to tools in other languages besides shell script.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell script, write the variables to another file like below and source these files in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

```
echo "export FOO=bar" >> environment.sh
```

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, source it like below:

```
source Path-to-file/environment.sh
```

You can then access it globally.