# How to customize virtualenv shell prompt

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

How do you define a custom prompt to use when activating a [Python virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)?

I have a bash script for activating a virtualenv I use when calling specific [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) commands. I want the shell prompt to say something like "(fab)" so I can easily distinguish it from other shells I have open. Following [this](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/) example, I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dir=`dirname $0`
cd $script_dir
/bin/bash -c ". .env/bin/activate; PS1='(fab) '; exec /bin/bash -i"
```

but there's no change to the prompt. What am I doing wrong?

---

Comment: are you sourcing this script or running as child process ?

Answer (score 5):

The prompt is set in the virtualenv's activate script (located in the bin folder under the virtualenv). If you only want to change the prompt some times, you could set an environment variable before calling activate (make sure to clear it in the corresponding deactivate file). If you simply want the prompt to be different all the time, you can do that right in activate at the line that looks like

```
set "PROMPT=(virtualenvname) %PROMPT%"
```

If you're using virtualenvwrapper, you could do all of this in the postactivate and postdeactivate scripts as well.

Comment: Your instructions are a little confusing. I only want to do this when called from the sample shell script I posted. How would I incorporate this into my script? Simply adding `PROMPT='(fab)'` like you suggest does not work.

Comment: You would need to set an environment variable in your shell script, then modify the activate script to set a different prompt if it your environment variable exists. If you look in the activate script, there are already sections with if/ else logic for environment variables. Just make sure to clear the variable in deactivate or you'll wind up always hitting the if case.

Comment: @Tom, The activate script just looks for `PS1`, which I'm already defining. What environment variable are you referring to? How would I define it?

Comment: You'd set the variable in the bash script you mention [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable) and then look for the presence of the variable in the activate script.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to do this via a script executed as a child process. Calling a separate bash process seems to forget any previously set `PS1`. However, it turned out to be trivial if I just sourced the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dir=`dirname $0`
cd $script_dir
. .env/bin/activate
PS1="(fab) "
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the

```
exec /bin/bash -i
```

is resetting the PS1 variable. When I run

```
export PS1="foo "; bash
```

it resets it too. Curiously, when I look into the bash sources (shell.c and variables.c) it appears to use

```
set_if_not ("PS1", primary_prompt);
```

to init it. But I'm not exactly sure what happens between this and main(). Giving up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) and on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) (RedHat CentOS) as well. I found solution for both.

**CYGWIN**

After some investigation I found that the problem is that PS1 is set by /etc/bash.bashrc which overrides the PS1 env.var. So You need to disable to run this file using:

```
/bin/bash -c ". .env/bin/activate; PS1='(fab) ' exec /bin/bash -i --norc"
```

or

```
/bin/bash -c ". .env/bin/activate; export PS1='(fab) '; exec /bin/bash -i --norc"
```

**LINUX**

It works much simpler:

```
/bin/bash -c ". .env/bin/activate; PS1='(fab) ' exec /bin/bash -i"
```

or

```
/bin/bash -c ". .env/bin/activate; export PS1='(fab) '; exec /bin/bash -i"
```

If the script You are calling does not export the variables (and I suppose it does not) and the set variables does not appears in the environment then You could try something like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "PS1='(fab) ' exec /bin/bash --rcfile .env/bin/activate; "
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: None of these do anything for me. The last one even throws the error "/bin/bash: --: invalid option"

Comment: Cerin: Which version of bash you use? And on which platform?

Comment: 4.2.25 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Cerin: Sorry! I did not realize that '--rcfile' somehow does not like if mixed with short options! Remove '-i' before '--rcfile' in the last `bash` line.

Comment: That fixes the error, but it still doesn't show the custom PS1 value.

Comment: @cerin: could you try the --norc version?