# Is there a way to customize the name appearance of current python virtual environment in terminal?

Tags: python

[image: This is how the name looks now.]

What I want to do, is to change the color, remove whitespace, use square brackets instead of round ones.

Comment: setting `$PS1` should be enough

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Beginner - How to customize the output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579140/python-beginner-how-to-customize-the-output-window)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [How to customize virtualenv shell prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524692/how-to-customize-virtualenv-shell-prompt) with two added ingredients:

1. You want to apply coloring.
2. You did not specify your OS/shell; perhaps you are interested in any OS/shell, or at least the two most common, Win10 and bash.

So here you can find complete info.

Bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-ps1-prompt.

Win10:
https://superuser.com/questions/427820/how-to-change-only-the-prompt-color-of-the-windows-command-line.
See also [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line)