# Git warning: unknown trace value for 'GIT_TRACE'

Tags: java, git

[image]

As shown in the figure above; Every time you operate git command, some warning messages will appear.
I found some answers on the Internet;
For example, the following：

[image]

Only valid for git GUI; When I close the GIT GUI and reopen it, the warning message still exists;
I tried another way:I modified a configuration file in the GIT installation directory
[image]
I added a line of code: unset GIT_ TRACE_ PACKET GIT_ TRACE.
In this way, there will be no warning message through git GUI operation; However, when I operate through the console of idea, the warning message still exists and cannot be eliminated; May I ask you guys how to solve this problem?

Comment: I can't see any reason that this question should be tagged `[java]`. Do you have any reasons to believe that your problem is related to your use of Java?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing at all to do with [java](/questions/tagged/java).

You get this message because you have `GIT_TRACE` set in your environment, to a value that Git does not understand.  Your scripts as written cannot change your shell's setting.  See [environment-variables](/questions/tagged/environment-variables), and, e.g., [Best way to set environment variables in calling shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21325627/1256452) and [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496702/1256452).

To unset `GIT_TRACE` in your current shell, run `unset GIT_TRACE`.  To set it to a different variable, run `export GIT_TRACE=value`.  The set of valid *`value`*-s includes `0` (off—this has the same effect as un-setting the variable), `1` and `2` (on and trace goes to stderr), higher numeric values (trace goes to an already-open file descriptor), and path names starting with `/`.

Any *new* shells you create may get `GIT_TRACE` set based on dot-files (e.g., `.bashrc`) or other startup items you have chosen.  To change this, find your startup items and modify them.  If your GUI creates a new shell every time you ask it to do anything, you will have to use this method.