# Windows 10, kill child process, can't get correct PID

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, cmd, terminal

I use win10 if it's matters, in bash(git)

I have SH script:

```
start node ./e2e-tests/apimocker_runner.js & pid1=$!
start npm run protractor -- --binaryPath=./build/appInstaller/win-unpacked/ & pid2=$!

sleep 10
kill $pid1
kill $pid2
```

when i try kill processes by pid i have error:

```
bash: kill: (6616) - No such process
```

As i know in `$!` we have last child process pid, but this don't work.

Cuz then i type in bash:

```
start bash & pid=$!
echo $pid
```

> $pid === 1000  (for example)

but if i type

```
echo $$
```

in created bash by previous command i have another pid

> $$ ==== 1200 (for example)

Also I found what if i type `start bash` this create non-child process, but i want to create child process and wait for them like `wait $pid`

How i can do this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way for Power Shell to be involved here, if it really is, you need to explain how.  In the meantime, I changed the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable

Comment: Also [don't use `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill) when just `kill` will do.

Answer (score 1):

A variable set in one `bash` instance is not visible in another `bash` instance which is not its child process (and only then if the parent did `export variable` to expose it to children).

Comment: but problem is: i type kill -9 $myPid in 1st bash, where i did start bash

Comment: `start bash` starts a different Bash instance.  `myPid` contains the PID of that Bash instance (assuming `start` preserves the PID; not sure about this detail).  If that's not what you want, describe what you actually want -- code which doesn't do what you expect is an awful way to explain what you *do*  expect.

Comment: i have 2 scripts, on another computer i should start SH script,
then this script call 2 bash console with some command, when i want to kill this 2 process

SH:
    start node ./e2e-tests/...
    start npm run protractor ..
when i want 2 kill this process, i check, pid in called bash, its dofferent from pid what i have in $pid in parent bash

Comment: You are adding new code, not explaining the code you have in your question.

Comment: I asq how 2 kill process, then write for what i need this. Start script in 2 bash and kill them

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what *exactly* you are having trouble with.  What do you do, how does it fail, what should it look like?  If English is not a strong language for you, perhaps this is not a suitable forum for your question.