# Set an env variable in one npm script that can later be accessed in another script

Tags: typescript, npm, jestjs, environment-variables, package.json

In the package's `package.json`, I have two scripts. One starts the server for testing, and one starts the tests:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --no-inline",
  "test": "jest"
}
```

Note that `start` is a background script that starts a server then stays running in the terminal until it is manually interrupted (Ctrl + C). So the `npm run test` script must be executed in a separate terminal.

However, the server can also be started from another server package (using lerna in the context of a monorepo), as offered by that package's `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "debug": "DEBUG=* ts-node src/"
}
```

Likewise, this is also background script that starts a server then stays running in the terminal until it is manually interrupted (Ctrl + C).

I want my test files to know how the server was started when the script `npm run test` is executed. This could be done by setting or altering an env variable in the start script, that is later inspected in the test files. If that env variable is set then the test will know that its server was started by a user running `npm run start` in that package before hand. If not, then the tests will know that the server was started by a user doing `npm run debug` in the other package. It would then be able to run some conditional code, such as:

```
if (process.env.server_from_start) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

I have gotten as far as sharing an env variable from within a script, by doing:

```
"scripts": {
  "script1": "export FOO=bar && bash script_that_echos_FOO.sh",
  "script2": "bash script_that_echos_FOO.sh"
}
```

FOO is echoed correctly when I run `npm run script1`, but nothing is echoed when I run `npm run script2`.

Comment: Conventionally `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'` when a script is executed by test runner. This includes Jest. It doesn't need to be set manually. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Not quite. I want to set an environment variable in one script, and then retrieve it in another script (where both scripts are defined in the same package).

Editted OP to show current progress.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your case correctly but it seems it's not possible to do what you're trying to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable , and may not be desirable for environment variables to persist. If you want totally unrelated scripts to communicate with each other, you likely need some other way rather than shell environment.

Comment: I think in the end it is possible to persist an env file across scripts, but not in any clean way that is natively supported by npm. Something like writing the env variable to a `.env` file, then retrieving it from that `.env` file in the second script (or via some js file that the second script calls using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package). This does seem to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. A file is the most simple way to exchange information between processes. The problem happens when it's not cleaned up on exit and affects future launches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution from [this](https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/flexible-npm-scripts-89b5ec0c5b46) article in the paragraph titled `Accessing variables in multiple scripts`.

The idea is that the `runner` script is responsible for setting the cross-script environment variable and running a subsequent script. When `runner` spawns a child process running the subsequent script `script1/script2`, the child process will have access to the defined environment variable from `runner`. I believe that is why when you ran your original `script2` there was no output, because the original `script1` and `script2` were run in independent processes.

Updated scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "runner": "FOO=bar npm run",
    "script1": "bash script_that_echos_FOO.sh",
    "script2": "bash another_script_that_echos_FOO.sh",
    "multiScript": "npm-run-all script1 script2" 
}
```

The `runner` script would be invoked with the following. The parameter after `--` is appended to end of the `runner` script and tells which script to run after setting the `FOO` environment variable.

In addition, I've added how you could run multiple scripts using [`npm-run-all`](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) so that all the scripts spawned from `runner` have access to the `FOO` environment variable.

```
npm run runner -- script1 // script1 runs and has access to FOO
npm run runner -- script2 // script2 runs and has access to FOO
npm run runner -- multiScript // script1 and script2 run (sequentially) with both having access to FOO
```

I want to add that this method is really beneficial when you have a dynamic environment variable that needs to be set. For my purpose it was to retrieve and set a token needed prior to executing some tests. The following example sets the environment variable to the result of a script.

```
"scripts": {
    "runner": "FOO=$(node ./retrieveDynamicToken.js) npm run",
    ...
}
```