# Why do CUDA asynchronous errors occur? （occur on the linux OS）

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cuda, gpu

> CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
> For debugging consider passing `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`.
> Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I try the enter the command in the bash: `export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` and it worked. However, I am not sure whether this way affects the GPU(s) efficiency or not. Can I change some setting to make it the default such that I do not have to type this command line every time?

Comment: Yes it affects efficiency. If there is a runtime error that doesn't appear with launch-blocking, you should find and fix that error.

Comment: Technically you can put `export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` into some startup script like `$HOME/.bash_profile`. But as said above it is a bad idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a bash script to set global environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable)