# Set variables for multiple linux Scripts from external file

Tags: linux, bash, variables, external

I have a linux script job that is made up of 7 scripts in total to complete the job.
There are about 60 Variables defined at the start of each script.
These variables will be constant & identical in each of the 7 scrips.

The problem I have is that when I am working on the scripts, I have to copy paste all variables to all scripts each time I update or modify variable(s)

Is there a way that I can define all the variables in a file "variables.txt" & somehow reference all these variables from variables.txt at the start of each script?

I was thinking of using sed, but there is probably an easier & cleaner way..

Comment: Yes you can. Put the line `. variables.txt` just below  `#!/bin/bash` in each script and you're done. Make sure they are all in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the constants, and use source in each script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source `dirname $0`/variables.txt
```

(The `dirname $0` part is to ensure that no matter how the script is called, it looks for variables.txt in the same directory as the script.)

Comment: I tried that but scripts are not working as they should.  Some of the scripts are copied to a temp-working folder to be executed, could that be the problem

Comment: As long as `variables.txt` is in your path, `source variables.txt` should find it.

Comment: Well, can you have the process that copies those scripts also copy varaibles.txt to the same place?

If variables.txt is always going to be in a known place, you can just use the whole path:
    source /path/to/my/variables/file/variables.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set global variables, all the scripts will recognise it:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bar
export FOO
```

[Define Global Variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)