# Accessing system wide environment variables inside a bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've added a system wide environment variable in /etc/environment. I want to access this variable in a bash script. Is there any way to access it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "system-wide environment variable". They only exist per process.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that PATH is an environmental variable, also in /etc/environment, I can access path in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo $PATH
```

So what's wrong with your variable?

Comment: I was able to print the path in my bash script.But the new variable I set recently is not reflecting in the script.Do I need a system reboot to take effect?

Comment: Ok thats something different. It's like exporting PATH into "something" in a bash session. The changes last only for this session. If you want to change the value of the PATH permantly, your script may need to edit /etc/environment (or do some export in .bashrc and then source .bashrc). Hope it helps