# Why my file does not get sourced from bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script where at some point, I want to source the `${HOME}/.profile` file which should add `${HOME}/.local/bin` to the $PATH. But when I check the path with `echo $PATH`, `${HOME}/.local/bin` is absent as if the source did not happen. What am I doing wrong?

```
if command -v pip3 &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Pip is already installed."
else
    echo "Pip is not installed. Installing Pip..."
    cd ${HOME}/Downloads
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
    su -c "python3 get-pip.py --user" "$SUDO_USER"

    cat <<-'EOT' >> "${HOME}/.profile"
    # set PATH so it includes user's private .local/bin if it exists
    if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
    fi
    EOT

    source "${HOME}/.profile"         #this is not happening!!!
    rm ${HOME}/Downloads/get-pip.py
    echo "Pip has been installed."
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Fixed the script syntax as suggest by Kusalananda.

Comment: Are you checking the `PATH` _in_ the script or after running the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script can't modify the environment of the shell from whence it was executed.

Sourcing `~/.profile` in the script will not set the path in the interactive shell that originally started the script. To do that, you would have to *source* your script.

Also, your here-document would need to be quoted, or the *current* values of `HOME` and `PATH` would be inserted into the `.profile` file:

```
cat <<'PROFILE_END' >> "$HOME/.profile"
# set PATH so it includes user's private .local/bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
PROFILE_END
```

Also note that if  the user is a `bash` user with an existing `~/.bash_profile` file, then the `~/.profile` file will be ignored for that user when a new login shell is started.

I'm further unsure why you `su` to `$USER`.  It seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited my post. What do you mean by "you would have to source your script"? When I open another shell after the script has run, the path is still not updated although the `~/.local/bin` directory exists. I made it work by appending the lines to `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.profile`.

Comment: @StephaneB. If you want to have the changes to the `.profile` active in the same shell as you run your script from, then you must execute the modification to `PATH` in the same shell environment. This could be done by using `source` on your script.  If you have a `~/.bash_profile` file, the `~/.profile` file will not be used (as I mentioned).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script helped me to understand better.