# Augmenting path on Linux using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment

I'm trying to create a bash script that will let me augment the path everytime I execute it. Here is the code I have to point towards where I'm going:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to augment path
echo "what directories do you want to add:"
read MYNEWPATH
echo "adding the "$MYNEWPATH" directory to PATH"
export PATH
echo "your new env variable is now:"
echo $PATH
exit 0
```

when i run it and cmd asks for a new directory, I enter the directory i want to add but it says "line 6: PATH: command not found"

Open for all suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Line 6? Is that `export PATH`? Are you sure you don't have a line `PATH = "$PATH:$MYNEWPATH"` in there? In any case, [no you can't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: This seems like a lot of effort to just do: `PATH+="/new/path/1:/new/path/2"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to append the new variable to the old path (line 4), like so:

```
export PATH=$MYNEWPATH:$PATH
```

But, when you run a script, BASH fires off a new child process and the altered PATH variable reverts once the script is finished running.  To handle this you can use the script to create a **sourcefile** and then `source` it so that the new path persists in the parent shell environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter new path: "
read MYNEWPATH
echo export PATH=$MYNEWPATH:$PATH > sourcefile
```

After you have run the script, a new file is created that you can source into the parent shell.  All you have to do from there is `source sourcefile` and your new, altered path exists in your current environment.

You'll most likely want to tweak the code so that the **sourcefile** is created in a specific spot.  You can then use an alias to automate the process further.

You might also find this of some help: [how to alter path within a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23426/how-to-alter-path-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: Instead of invoking a script and then sourcing a file, you can just make this script into a function: `pathadd() { PATH+=:$1; printf "%s\n" "New path:" "$PATH"; }; pathadd /foo/bar`