# Install homebrew using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew using Dockerfile but I am unable to do so. I have the following statement (based on the alternative installation steps on https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux):

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
RUN brew --version
```

The last line throws an error saying "brew command not found".

I am able to run the same exact steps using ENTRYPOINT and specifying a bash file.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `eval` happens in the first `RUN` statement, but is not persisted through to the next one. You want to join the two.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) \
&& brew --version
```

Generally speaking, any environment changes you perform in one shell instance (one `RUN` statement, or your `ENTRYPOINT`) will be lost as soon as that instance terminates. See also [Global environment variables in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Thanks tripleee, that solved it! Running to another issue when I try to install a package as part of the build which installs just fine but when I run the container it cant resolve the package name! I just appended the following to your script "&& brew tap aws/tap &&brew install aws-sam-cli". Again this whole thing works if I run through entrypoint.sh. I am baffled!

Comment: Each `RUN` statement is one shell instance (one process). `entrypoint.sh` is also one shell instance. As long as the `eval` executes in the same shell instance as `brew --version` you should be fine. Perhaps read up on the Unix process model if this is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add it to the PATH ?

`export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH`