# Python, the relationship between the bash/python/subprocess processes (shells)?

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess

When trying to write script with python, I have a fundamental hole of knowledge.

**Update:** Thanks to the answers I corrected the word `shell` to `process/subprocess`

### Nomenclature

- Starting with a Bash prompt, lets call this `BASH_PROCESS`
- Then within `BASH_PROCESS` I run `python3 foo.py`, the python script runs in say `PYTHON_SUBPROCESS`
- Within `foo.py` is a call to `subprocess.run(...)`, this subprocess command runs in say `SUBPROCESS_SUBPROCESS
- Within `foo.py` is `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)`, this subprocess command runs in say `SUBPROCESS_SUBPROCESS=True`

### Test for if a process/subprocess is equal

Say `SUBPROCESS_A` starts `SUBPROCESS_B`. In the below questions, when I say is `SUBPROCESS_A` == `SUBPROCESS_B`, what I means is if `SUBPROCESS_B` sets an env variable, when it runs to completion, will they env variable be set in `SUBPROCESS_A`? If one runs `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in `SUBPROCESS_B`, will `SUBPROCESS_A` now have an ssh agent too?

### Question

Using the above nomenclature and equality tests

1. Is `BASH_PROCESS` == `PYTHON_SUBPROCESS`?
2. Is `PYTHON_SUBPROCESS` == `SUBPROCESS_SUBPROCESS`?
3. Is `PYTHON_SUBPROCESS` == `SUBPROCESS_SUBPROCESS=True`?
4. If `SUBPROCESS_SUBPROCESS=True` is not equal to `BASH_PROCESS`, then how does one alter the executing environment (e.g. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`) so that a python script can set up the env for the calller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing several concepts here.

TLDR No, there is no way for a subprocess to change its parent's environment. See also [Global environment variables in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)

You really don't seem to be asking about "shells".
Instead, these are *subprocesses;* if you run `python foo.py` in a shell, the Python process is a subprocess of the shell process. (Many shells let you `exec python foo.py` which replaces the shell process with a Python process; this process is now a subprocess of whichever process started the shell. On Unix-like systems, ultimately all processes are descendants of process 1, the `init` process.)

`subprocess` runs a subprocess, simply. If `shell=True` then the immediate subprocess of Python is the shell, and the command(s) you run are subprocesses of that shell. The shell will be the default shell (`cmd` on Windows, `/bin/sh` on Unix-like systems) though you can explicitly override this with e.g. `executable="/bin/bash"`

Examples:

- `subprocess.Popen(['printf', '%s\n', 'foo', 'bar'])`

  Python is the parent process, `printf` is a subprocess whose parent is the Python process.
- `subprocess.Popen(r"printf '%s\n' foo bar", shell=True)`

  Python is the parent process of `/bin/sh`, which in turn is the parent process of `printf`. When `printf` terminates, so does `sh`, as it has reached the end of its script.

  Perhaps notice that the shell takes care of parsing the command line and splitting it up into the four tokens we ended up explicitly passing directly to `Popen` in the previous example.

  The commands you run have access to shell features like wildcard expansion, pipes, redirection, quoting, variable expansion, background processing, etc.

  In this isolated example, none of those are used, so you are basically adding an unnecessary process. (Maybe use `shlex.split()` if you want to avoid the minor burden of splitting up the command into tokens.) See also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)
- `subprocess.Popen(r"printf '%s\n' foo bar", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")`

  Python is the parent process of Bash, which in turn is the parent process of `printf`. Except for the name of the shell, this is identical to the previous example.

  There are situations where you really need the slower and more memory-hungry Bash shell, when the commands you want to execute require features which are available in Bash, but not in the Bourne shell. In general, a better solution is nearly always to run as little code as possible in a subprocess, and instead replace those Bash commands with native Python constructs; but if you know what you are doing (or *really* don't know what you are doing, but need to get the job done rather than solve the problem properly), the facility can be useful.

(Separately, you should probably avoid bare `Popen` when you can, as explained in the `subprocess` documentation.)

Subprocesses inherit the environment of their parent when they are started. On Unix-like systems, there is no way for a process to change its parent's environment (though the parent may participate in making that possible, as in your `eval` example).

To perhaps accomplish what you may ultimately be asking about, you can set up an environment within Python and then start your other command as a subprocess, perhaps then with an explicit `env=` keyword argument to point to the environment you want it to use:

```
import os

...
env = os.environ.copy()
env["PATH"] = "/opt/foo:" + env["PATH"]
del env["PAGER"]
env["secret_cookie"] = "xyzzy"
subprocess.Popen(["otherprogram"], env=env)
```

or have Python print out values in a form which can safely be passed to `eval` in the Bourne shell. (Caution: this requires you to understand the perils of `eval` in general and the target shell's quoting conventions in particular; also, you will perhaps need to support the syntax of more than one shell, unless you are only targeting a very limited audience.)

... Though in many situations, the simplest solution by far is to set up the environment in the shell, then run Python as a subprocess of that shell instance (or `exec python` if you want to get rid of the shell instance after it has performed its part; see also [What are the uses of the exec command in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts))

---

Python without an argument starts the Python REPL, which could be regarded as a "shell", though we would commonly not use that term (perhaps instead call it "interactive interpreter" - see also below); but `python foo.py` simply runs the script `foo.py` and exits, so there is no shell there.

The definition of "shell" is slightly context-dependent, but you don't really seem to be asking about shells here. (Some GUIs have a concept of "graphical shell" etc but we are already out of the scope of what you were trying to ask about.) Some programs are command interpreters (the Python executable interprets and executes commands in the Python language; the Bourne shell interprets and executes shell scripts) but generally only those whose primary purposes include running other programs are called "shells".

Comment: A related FAQ is "how can I `source` a piece of shell script in Python?" Obviously, you can't (short of reimplementing relevant parts of the shell in Python) so eventually this resolves to the same question, with the same solution: run a shell, then run Python from that after you have initialized the environment.

Comment: Thank you for this indepth answer. This python can never replace bash scripting, since you can't create a python script to be sourced for setting up your environment like you can with bash. I am much better with python that bash, so this is a unfortunate for me. Thank you for demystifying the calling process for me, explains why many attempts I tried have failed.

Comment: `run a shell, then run Python from that after you have initialized the environment.`, I wanted to initialise the environment with python because I struggle with bash, but now I understand its not possible, and must move on, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

None of those equalities are true, and half of those "shells" aren't actually shells.

Your bash shell is a shell. When you launch your Python script from that shell, the Python process that runs the script is a child process of the bash shell process. When you launch a subprocess from the Python script, that subprocess is a child process of the Python process. If you launch the subprocess with `shell=True`, Python invokes a shell to parse and run the command, but otherwise, no shell is involved in running the subprocess.

Child processes inherit environment variables from their parent on startup (unless you take specific steps to avoid that), but they cannot set environment variables for their parent. You cannot run a Python script to set environment variables in your shell, or run a subprocess from Python to set your Python script's environment variables.