# unable to run source command with find -exec

Tags: linux, bash, find

1. FAIL

```bash
find ${settings_base} -type f -exec source {} \;
```

> ```
> find: ‘source’: No such file or directory
> ```

2. PASS

```bash
for f in $(find ${settings_base} -type f); do
    source "${f}"
done
```

I just want to know the reason for FAIL.

Comment: The reason is that `source` is a shell built-in.

Comment: @Poshi, I'm not sure you're right. I tried recreating it with `.` and that runs, but I do get the same error with `source`. @k_vishwanath, try with `.`?

Comment: Whether or not it gets an error, it can't really work. The point of `source` (and the near-equivalent `.` command) is to run a script *in the current shell* rather than as a subprocess like normal. But `find` itself is already a subprocess of the current shell, so even if it were able to parse and execute shell commands itself (which it can't do), it cannot execute them in what, from its point of view, is the parent shell.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, so what causes the difference? And how would you achieve the desired result?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code snippets in the question.  The Shellcheck reports include links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Well, if you think that `source` is not a built-in but a real program, can you point me to the location in your disk of the corresponding binary image of that command? If you manage to do an `ls` of that command, I'll buy your hypothesis.
Anyways, as others said, if you manage to overcome this "small issue", then you will find that your final environment is in the same state as before, so the code won't work for your purposes even if it were not failing.

Answer (score 3):

The `-exec` predicate of `find` runs a subprocess. But `source` cannot be run as a subprocess.

Shell built-ins like `source` (and `cd`, etc) modify the environment of the currently running shell instance. They don't exist as external commands (there is no `/bin/source` or `/usr/bin/source` etc) because they *cannot* work as external commands. Recall that a subprocess cannot modify the environment of its parent process, for reasons of security as well as for architectural reasons (see also e.g. [Global environment variables in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script) for background). So as a matter of fact, even if `find` could somehow execute `source`, it could only modify the environment of the `find` process, and then when `find` exits, any effects of that would be lost, and your currently running shell instance would be back where it was before you ran `find`.

The workaround you already discovered is the way to do it, though for complete robustness, you would also have to guard against whitespace or other shell metacharacters in the `find` output. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 has a detailed discussion, but I won't repeat all the nuances and corner cases here; click through to the linked page for that.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  source "$f"
done < <(find $settings_base -type f -print0)
```

(Notice that `-print0` is a GNU extension, and so not properly portable to various non-Linux platforms.)

Depending on what `$settings_base` contains, it should probably be double-quoted; if it contains multiple values, put them in an array and use `"${settings_base_array[@]}"`. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bash 4.3 (released in 2014) or later you can do what you want without using `find`:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

settings_base=$1

shopt -s dotglob globstar

for f in "$settings_base"/**; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && source -- "$f"
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (released in 2014) because it follows symlinks.

  See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for more information about the `globstar` and `dotglob` settings.