# Why and when do source and dot behave differently in find -exec {}

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I have heard it said, [multiple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094271/using-dot-or-source-while-calling-another-script-what-is-the-difference), that in Bash `source` is merely an alias for `.`. Even in [the Bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins). However, I've noticed, while digging into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981915/unable-to-run-source-command-with-find-exec#76982272) that they are not identical when called via `find`. Here is a reproducible example:

I've created a file called `test.sh`

```
uberhumus@pc:~/tmp$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Kazabooboo"
uberhumus@pc:~/tmp$ find ~/tmp -type f -iname "test.sh" -exec . {} \;
find: ‘.’: Permission denied
uberhumus@pc:~/tmp$ ind ~/tmp -type f -iname "test.sh" -exec source {} \;
find: ‘source’: No such file or directory
```

My question is what causes the difference, and are there any other differences that aren't discussed?

Comment: Find's exec executes commands. Dot (`.`) and `source` are shell builtins, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109222 BTW, in your example with find `.` is interpreted as the current directory, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: They do not behave differently in `bash`. `bash`has nothing to do with it. You aren't executing `bash` at all here. You are attempting to execute (1) `.` and (2) `source`. Neither succeeded, for the reasons shown. Off topic.

Comment: Should I and can I move this question to a different stackexchange, and if so how? @user207421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, `source` and `.` are the same, as the man page says.

What you are doing here is testing if `find` treats `source` and `.` the same way. It does not. `find` understands that `.` is the current directory. You cannot `exec` the current directory; permission is denied.

if `find` needs to execute `source`, there must be an external program `source` available. There is none in your `PATH`, so you get `No such file or directory`

The fact that they are different for `find` does not imply that there is a difference for `bash`.