# Change directory of parent process after exit

Tags: c, chdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process)

Is possible to make the change of directory persist after program exit? Since it resets to original directory when program exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child process cannot affect its parent's current directory, any more than it can really affect its parent's [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables).  If the child removes the parent's current directory, it makes it so that the parent doesn't have a named current directory, but that's about all.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Why do you wish that the directory changes?