# How can I change my current directory in a c program?

Tags: c

I'm new in c programming and I'm asking for a simple way to change my current directory in a programm. I tried to use `system("new path")` but it didn't work.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir

Comment: How would you do it in the terminal? BTW, show your code and explain what is "_not working_"

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is that system is starting a separate process, changing its working directory, then exiting. Your program needs to change its own directory by calling `chdir`.

Comment: i tried also chdir("new path") and it isn't working either and i'm working at windows

Comment: You can't change the user's directory from a separate program. The program can only change its own directory. After it exits the user command line is still in the same dirr.

Comment: Well, CD does it by changing its parent's directory.

Comment: i told you i tried system("cd new path") and it's not working

Comment: Because system starts a separate process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a unix based OS, use [`chdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir). For windows you'll have to use [`_chdir()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx), although an alias chdir exists, it is deprecated.

Both the functions return 0 on success and -1 if an error occurred.

You can only change the directory in which the program executes. **You can't change the working directory of your shell.**