# How do I change directory in python so it remains after running the script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the terminal directory through a python script. I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python/431715) and others like it so I know about os.chdir, but it's not working the way I'd like. os.chdir appears to change the directory, but only for the python script. For instance I have this code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os

os.chdir("/home/chekid/work2/")
print os.getcwd()
```

Unfortunately after running I'm still in the directory of the python script (e.g. /home/chekid) rather than the directory I want to be in. See below.

```
gandalf(pts/42):~> pwd
/home/chekid

gandalf(pts/42):~> ./changedirectory.py
/home/chekid/work2

gandalf(pts/42):~> pwd
/home/chekid
```

Any thoughts on what I should do?

*Edit*: Looks like what I'm trying to do doesn't exist in 'normal' python. I did find a work around, although it doesn't look so elegant to me.

```
 cd `./changedirectory.py`
```

Comment: The python script changes it's own directory. Bash doesn't change. Note that what are you asking is the same as assuming that if you open a file in a python script, the file should also open on your desktop

Comment: You cannot do it. That's why `cd` is always a shell built-in command, not an external program.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to use `os.system()`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process

Comment: @SantoshKumar: Won't work, `system` sort of "runs its own shell".

Comment: A little more looking reveals that while **still a *bad* idea**, this can be done (relatively) simply through some calls to `gdb`: https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/the-shell-challenge-changing-another-process-working-directory. That link lists the caveats: `bash` doesn't realize it's CWD has been changed, and so on.

Comment: In Bash you can make an alias, like this: `alias mycd="cd \`./changedirectory.py\`"`

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  The shell's current directory belongs to the shell, not to you.

(OK, you could [`ptrace(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) the shell and make it call [`chdir(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir), but that's probably not a great design, won't work on Windows, and I would not *begin* to know how to do it in pure Python except that you'd probably have to mess around with ctypes or something similar.)

You could launch a subshell with your current working directory.  That might be close enough to what you need:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/somewhere')
shell = os.environ.get('SHELL', '/bin/sh')
os.execl(shell, shell)
# execl() does not return; it replaces the Python process with a new shell process
```

The original shell will still be there, so make sure you don't leave it hanging around.  If you initially call Python with the `exec` builtin (e.g. `exec python /path/to/script.py`), then the original shell will be replaced with the Python process and you won't have to worry about this.  But if Python exits without launching the shell, you'll be left with no shell open at all.

Comment: That sounds like a fun project :-). I guess if you could find the code area you could do, basically, a code injection attack. Huh.

Comment: @Linuxios: I'm not sure I'd call it an "attack," exactly.  You're basically just doing the gdb trick by hand.

Answer (score 4):

You can if you cheat: Make a bash script that calls your python script. The python script returns the path you want to change directory to. Then the bash script does the acctual chdir. Of course you would have to run the bash script in your bash shell using "source".

Comment: For more inspiration, take a look at this list of NCD clones http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/norton_change_directory_clones.shtml

Answer (score 3):

The current working directory is an attribute of a process. It cannot be changed by another program, such as changing the current working directory in your shell by running a separate Python program. This is why `cd` is *always* a shell built-in command.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your python print the directory you want to move to, and then call your script with cd "$(./python-script.py)". In condition your script actually does not print anything else.