# Running 'export' command with Pythons 'subprocess' does not work

Tags: python, bash, shell, command, subprocess

```
subprocess.run('export FOO=BAR', shell=True)
```

This simply doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

All I am trying to do I set an environment variable from my python (3.5.1) script, and when I run the above line, nothing happens. No errors are raised, and when I check the environment variable myself, it has not been set.

Other shell commands with `subprocess.run()` *do* work, such as `ls` and `pwd`, but not `export`.

`.run()` was added in Python 3.5 (in case you didn't recognise it), but I have also tried the above line with `.call()` and `.Popen()`, with no change in results.

I am aware that I can set environment variables in python with `os.environ['FOO'] = "BAR"`, but I will be using shell commands a lot in my project, and I expect that I will need to string multiple commands together, which will make using `export` easier than `os.environ`.

My project will run on Linux, which is what my machine is running on.

Comment: think: each `subprocess.run(shell=True)` starts a new shell. Open two terminals and type `export FOO=BAR` in one terminal and `echo $FOO` in another (the second terminal that runs a separate shell won't see the new `$FOO` value). It is the same reason why `cd` is a shell builtin (because it changes the working directory of the current process and if it were a separate program then `cd` would had to change the environment of the parent process—that can't be done (normally)). See [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2375003/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works fine; however, the variable setting only exists in the subprocess. You cannot affect the environment of the local process from a child.

`os.environ` is the correct solution, as it changes the environment of the local process, and those changes will be inherited by any process started with `subprocess.run`.

You can also use the `env` argument to `run`:

```
subprocess.run(["cmdname", "arg1", "arg number 2"], env=dict(FOO='BAR', **os.environ))
```

This runs the command in a modified environment that includes `FOO=BAR` without modifying the current environment.

Comment: Ahhh. So is my only option to use `os.environ`, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are objecting to using `os.environ` so much. That *is* the Python equivalent of using the shell's builtin `export` command in a shell script.

Comment: Like I said, I expect to be stringing multiple commands together; I believe it would be easier to add `export` to a list of commands I will need to execute, rather than do so in a separate python function. That's fine though, I can figure something out. Thanks for your answer, it explained why it wasn't working as I expected :)

Comment: you could use `dict(os.environ, FOO='BAR')` instead of `dict(FOO='BAR', **os.environ)`