# How can I change the shell directory in the C language program?

Tags: c, linux, shell, directory, chdir

When I use chdir() to change the current directory, the program will not change when the program is shut down. So How can I apply chdir() to Shell after using chdir() and programs have been terminated?

Comment: **Why do you ask**? Please **edit the question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: You can think of modifying PWD environment variable (depending on your OS). But I've not tested it.

Comment: @LotoLo: changing `PWD`  won't affect the current directory of parent process (i.e. the shell's process)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141313/10947 (1st hit on gxxgle for "*chdir does not work in C*", BTW!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the working directory of the parent process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot do that** (changing your parent shell directory from inside a C program). The current directory is an attribute of every [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), and your shell runs in a different process than your program (so the shell process and your program's process have each their own current directory).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has several chapters related to your issue.

Perhaps you might add some *shell function* (e.g. into your `~/.bashrc` ...) which perhaps could use `eval`  to run your C program (which would output some `cd`  command, that the `eval`  or `source` builtin of your shell would handle within the *same* shell process); BTW [ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) might be inspirational. Actually I don't recommend this route if you are a newbie.

PS. You really should *motivate your question* and give a lot *more context*; it smells badly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `execl` just in case if needed to execute shell command

Comment: @Ashish: I don't understand what you mean (and how it is related to the OP's question), and that does not change the fact that every process has its own current directory.