# Change working directory from python or shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I like to do something like this in python or bash, where the program transform the given file path and move the current shell.

```
ulka:~/scc/utils$ python prog.py some_path1
ulka:some_path2$
```

Here

```
some_path1 -> prog.py -> some_path2
```

I tried with subprocess.call or os.chdir, but it's not work, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: you can't do that. `cd` is built-in.

Comment: Your python code runs in its own child process. It can't `cd` its parent process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since python runs in its own process, it won't be able to change the current directory of your shell. However, you could do something like this:

```
change_path() {
    # prog.py figures out the real path that you want and prints
    # it to standard output
    local new_path=$(python prog.py some_path1)  # could use an argument "$1"
    cd "$new_path"
}
```

Comment: Great, I like this idea.

Comment: nice solution for a near impossible problem. @Ulka accept the answer if you think it's the best one.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for a shell script to change your shell's current working directory if you run it with `source` or `.`. If you run your script like this, a `cd` command will be all you need. If you're running a shell script without `source` or `.`, or if you're running anything that's not a shell script, then there's no nice way to do it, and you'd be forced to resort to nasty hacks like injecting into the process with a debugger (not recommended, but see [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process) and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281994/changing-the-current-working-directory-of-a-certain-process if you really must do this).