# Set current working directory on exit (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, working-directory

I would like to have my application set the current working directory after my application is ran, meaning that, for example:

```
$ pwd
/my/directory
$ dotnet MyApp.dll
$ pwd
/another/place/somewhere
```

How can I do that in C# using .NET Core **in a cross-platform way**?

I looked at `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` but for both of them the working directory is reset to its original state when the application exits, as indicated in the documentation for `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`.

> When the application terminates, the working directory is restored to its original location (the directory where the process was started).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The current working directory is a property of each process.

To change it in the terminal, you need to find a way to tell the terminal to do it. A program that the terminal launches can change its own current directory, but not that of the calling terminal.

This is why `cd` is a built-in in shells. If it was an external program, it couldn't change the working directory of the shell/terminal.