# How to change directory in terminal?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSString *currentpath;

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/BestUser/Downloads"];


currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);
```

When I run it in the terminal, it logs that the path was changed to the directory Downloads.

But the my current directory in the terminal does not change.

Is there a way to change the directory in terminal via objective-c?

Comment: What terminal are you talking about? How is your script related to *some* terminal?

Comment: A terminal for macOS. In terminal, if I execute the compiled m file, ./ChangeDirectory, it doesn't change the directory in the terminal. How do I change the directory so that it reflects in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things potentially stopping this from working the way you describe.

First, `-[NSFileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:]` may return `NO`, indicating that it was unable to change the current directory as requested. This could happen because the path doesn't exist, or is otherwise inaccessible — and on macOS 10.15 Catalina, some paths (like Downloads) may be inaccessible to scripts as a security measure. Your code should check the return value of that method and handle the error case.

Second, even if you're not running Catalina or pick a folder that *is* accessible, running the compiled program in a shell won't change the current directory in that shell. This is deliberate behavior on the part of `bash` and similar shells, as described in [several](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141313/chdirdirectory-doesnt-change-directory-after-exiting-to-shell) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process) — your call changes the working directory for your process, but that change does not propagate to the parent process. (The last question linked there describes a way to get around this, but its author recommends against using that strategy.)

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Every process has its own `working directory`, that is, `PWD` environment variable. When you executing a command like `./ChangeDirectory` in current shell session, it starts another `subshell` which is a process for that command, **not all** the environment variables will be initialized to the `subshell` session, `PWD` is that one.

When you changed the current working directory / `PWD` variable in subshell, the new variable won't affect the parent process's environment. That makes your *not changed*.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code will change current directory for its own process. Also even if you change current directory in terminal - that change will be true only for one terminal sessions.

What is the objective? Are you trying to set current directory at system launch? Or are you trying to store files to a specific directory? There can be many ways to achieve that but you have to elaborate your exact requirement.