# help with using alias in bash shell

Tags: bash

i want to have an alias "t" to enter a folder and list the content there.

i tried with:

```
alias t="cd $1; ls -la"
```

but it just listed the folder i typed but did not enter it. i wonder why?

cause when i use this one:

alias b="cd ..; ls"

it went back to the parent and listed the content.

so i want the "t" do enter the folder i type in too.

someone knows how to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use aliases that way. You can, however, declare a function:

```
function t {
    cd "$1"
    ls -la
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass arguments into bash aliases.  You'll need to create a shell function like so:

```
function t { cd "$1" && ls -la; }
```

Edit: whoops, forgot the function and edited per Juliano's suggestion.

Comment: `function t` or `t()` at the beginning.

Comment: I suggest replacing `;` with `&&`. It doesn't make a lot of sense to run ls if the user mistypes the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

cd is tricky in bash.  The command you issued ran in a separate process than your bash shell, and that process terminated when it was done.  See [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Comment: Nope, that's not the reason in this case.

Comment: The `cd` command (chdir) cannot be implemented as an external.  It must be a shell built-in in order to be useful.  (That's because it changes the shell's own process state).  For similar reasons the `read` and `export` and `set` commands must also built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

In most UNIX shells (`csh`, `bash`, `zsh`) aliases are a form of *expansion*.  Thus they are not parsed like functions.  Any word in the interactive input stream which would be processed as a command will be scanned against the list of aliases and a simple string replacement will be performed (usually before any other forms of expansion).

If you need to process arguments then you want to define a *function* which is parsed and processed rather than simply being expanded like a macro.