# Run cd in script and stay in that directory - 'source' command not helping

Tags: unix, csh, cd

Tried using the answer found here:

[How to run 'cd' in shell script and stay there after script finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879431/how-to-run-cd-in-shell-script-and-stay-there-after-script-finishes)

When I add the 'source' command, the directory is still unchanged after script runs, regardless of whether I execute 'source  ' or call the script using an alias coded in cshrc.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to post your script because you must be doing something else, perhaps calling `cd` within a subshell itself.

Comment: I can verify that using "source" does work for me. What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: `source`'ing a `cd` script works fine in `tcsh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to remove "/bin/" from the cd command within this script, in order for the command to work as intended.  Removing this removes the subshell issue for this script.  Also, coding "$1" in the ls command was invalid in this context.

Comment: Why did you have these `/bin` s anyway? The shell finds standard utilities without path specifications, and some commands (like `cd` or `echo`) are built-ins.

Comment: Used another script as a pattern for the new one.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below, make sure your call to `cd` is *not* executing within a subshell.  If it is, this won't work, `source` or not.

#### Script with `cd` in subshell

```
#!/bin/bash

( cd /etc ) # thie exec's in a subshell
```

#### Output

```
$ pwd
/home/siegex
$ source ./cdafterend.sh && pwd
/home/siegex
```

#### Script with `cd` *not* in subshell

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc # no subshell here
```

#### Output

```
$ pwd
/home/siegex
$ source ./cdafterend.sh && pwd
/etc
```

Comment: Here is the code. #!/bin/tcsh -f -b /bin/echo ' ' /bin/cd $1 /bin/ls $1 /bin/echo ' '