# Create a shell script to run in bash in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell

WARNING! Getting pretty basic here guys...

I have a rather elaborate shell script that I wish to create, but am haveing difficulty with the most basic of commands so am struggling to get going.

I want to create a .sh file that I can simply run using BASH - 
If I place just CD in the file and run in BASH nothing happens, whereas running CD from the terminal obv. gets me home.

Could someone shed some light on this please... I am running OSX

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run 'cd' in shell script and stay there after script finishes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879431/how-to-run-cd-in-shell-script-and-stay-there-after-script-finishes)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script?lq=1

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing happens'?  When you run the script, a sub-process is forked, the file is parsed, the subshell cd's and exits, returning a value to the calling shell.  That's quite a bit of activity, and I left out many details!

Comment: Thanks, that link was the answer - and WIlliam Pursell... Like your answer :)

Comment: Will be far better 1.) describe the problem what you want achieve 2.) what tried, 3.) input data and the wanted output (if acceptable) 4.) without the "excuse-me" sentences(!)... ;) :)

Answer (score 2):

When you run a script you spawn a new sub-shell, your `cd` works in that and then you exit back to your orginal shell and your old present work directory - just as thought the `cd` never happened.  If you want to short cut `cd`s use a `alias` or a function. Something like:

```
go_dev() {
    cd /my/long/path/to/dev/env/
}
```

or

```
alias go_dev='cd /my/long/path/to/dev/env/'
```