# Change current directory for user in Python

Tags: python

I want to change a user's current working directory when they run a Python script. For example, if I have the following script called `chdir.py`:

```
import os
os.chdir('Desktop')
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
$ pwd
/Users/me
$ python chdir.py
$ pwd
/Users/me/Desktop
```

I know that `os.chdir(path)` changes the working directory *during the runtime*, but it resets when the script exits. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Python. But it is possible in a normal bash script. You just need to source it: `source chdir.sh`.

Comment: As @Sraw suggested, you can refer this link for bash script [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879431/how-to-run-cd-in-shell-script-and-stay-there-after-script-finishes)

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest you rethink your problem statement. Why do you wanna do it?  You may better add the location to system variables such as `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` etc. depending on your problem. You may wanna use `import sys; sys.path.append(your_directory)`

Comment: @RaviJoshi my goal was to manipulate the path of a `cd` command as a spell checker. So if you enter `cd Dekstop` it looks in the current path and sees that the closest match is `Desktop` and changes directories to there instead.

Comment: You need to hook your program with the terminal. Alternatively, you may design your own terminal, where you have full control over the user input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because the current working directory is an attribute of a process. This means it cannot be changed by another program, such as your python script.