# Problem in executing user defining shell commmand

Tags: bash, macos, shell, vim, sh

I am trying to learn the basics of shell. I used vim editro for creating my own list of commands to be executed. Here is the way I created the code
`vi mycommands`

then inside this file I wrote

```
   cd Documents
```

I am using macOS Catalina which has zsh by default but switched to bash

So when I write the following command in the terminal:

```
   $ sh +x mycommands
```

It shows

```
+cd Documents
```

The Documents has some files and directories but it is not changing directory.Where am I going wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that your Documents folder is empty?

Comment: no @glenn jackman Documents is not empty besides it not changing directory at all

Comment: What is the output of `sh -x mycommands`?

Comment: @hmm it worked... thanks!!!

Comment: Btw.: `bash` != `zsh` != `sh`

Comment: Uh, that's not supposed to make it work. If it worked, then it always worked. Please update your post with the output if there are still issues.

Comment: Wait but now it shows
+cd Documents 
after using sh +x mycommands
[I edited it mycommands to cd Documents]
what does that mean? @hmm

Comment: It means you have a shell script that ran `cd Documents`. The `-x` flag just echos the commands and their arguments as they are being run. It sounds like it's working, but the script doesn't actually do anything observable in the output. What are you expecting from this script?

Comment: change the directory to Documents.... new to shell scripting here @hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts run like `sh myscript` execute in a separate sub-shell, not the current shell. Changing directory inside a script will not cause your shell to change directory. If you want to change directory in your shell, you need to run the commands in your shell.

To do that, run:

`. ./myscript` (sh, bash) or `source ./myscript` (bash).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879431/how-to-run-cd-in-shell-script-and-stay-there-after-script-finishes).

Comment: Thank you so much ...appreciate it!