# Change directory permanently in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cd

I'm trying to change directory in a called bash script.
 For this I tried to use `cd` command. But after the script ends current directory is restoring to position before the script call. 
I also tried to change `PATH` variable but it didn't show any effect too.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See the second answer for a way to make it work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: Sorry for dupicating question. My mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you execute a shell script a new shell is started for execution of this script. This shell won't affect its parent processes.

To execute a script in your current shell's context use the `source` or `.`  commands:

```
. cd.sh
source cd.sh
```