# Unable to use cd within a bash script as intended

Tags: bash

Consider this script I wrote, which should go into parent directory, when no argument is given (the if ... part).

```
#/bin/bash

if (($# == 0))
then
  cd ..
else
  for basename
  do
    cd ${PWD%$basename*}$basename
  done
fi
```

The problem is, that if I execute it like this

```
./up.sh
```

the cd is executed in a subshell, rendering it useless.

If I execute the script using `source`, it works, but I don't want to call it that way (I makes calling the script to complicated, also you would expect to call it directly if found in the PATH).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 3):

An arbitrary program (such as your bash program) cannot change the working directory of the parent process, as that would pretty much break all existing processes that spawn children.

You should define a [bash alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) or [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) instead. As you have discovered, typing `source ./up.sh` (or shorter: `. ./up.sh`) works too.

Comment: @sehe What would be viable alternatives?

Comment: @sehe Thanks, added that to the answer.

Comment: @OliverWeiler E.g. `function cddown() { cd ..; }` (functions are superior in most respects)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a function instead of a script

```
function myscript()
{
     // use $1, $2, "$@" as usual in scripts

     local v1="bla"       # can use globals
     export PATH="$PATH"  # but global shell env too

     somedirectory=.. 
     cd $somedirectory
}
```

Alternatively, `alias` would work (but it doesn't support redirection, argument passing, flow control etc well, and you cannot nest them in `$()` IIRC).

Lastly source the existing script in the current shell like so:

```
source ./script.sh
```

ksh and bash have shorthands for that:

```
. ./script.sh
```

Beware of scripts with 'exit' statements though: they will exit the parent shell!