# Run a Bash script command in a specified folder

Tags: bash

In a Bash script, is it possible to run a command in a specific folder? For example, I'd like to create a script that prints the contents of the `/home` folder using `ls`, no matter which directory the script is saved in.

Comment: What's wrong with `ls /home` ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with shell scripting - thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use `cd` to change directory in a script (but it'll not affect its parent shell). Try

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh
cd /home
pwd
ls
```

It'll print current directory (which is `/home`) and list the content of it. No matter what location of `myscript.sh` is.

Comment: I found this question that led me to believe that it wasn't possible to use cd in a shell script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: So would it be better to use an alias (as suggested in the question above), or to simply use the cd command?

Comment: `bash` will start a subshell to run your script which cannot change directory of its parent shell.