# bash on Linux command has no effect when capturing error message

Tags: bash, unix

I tried to capture the error messages from commands in a variable like this,

```
# /dir1/dir2 exists so this command will succeed
errMsg=$(cd /dir1/dir2 2>&1)

# get 0 as expected
echo $?

# shows that I am still in the original directory not /dir1/dir2
pwd
```

Replacing the right hand side with `$(cd /dir1/dir2 2>&1)` gives the same result.

Does this mean I cannot capture error messages from shell commands?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an error message ? Btw : using `cd` in a subshell does not change the directory of the current shell, so the behaviour you described is expected

Comment: It _succeeds_, but it succeeds **in a subshell**, and changing the directory of the subshell doesn't impact the active directory of its parent.

Comment: Which is to say -- this isn't generic to all shell commands; it's a problem specific to "special builtins" that modify the state of the active instance. There are workarounds possible, but they're awful and I don't recommend any of them. (I'm adding an example of such an awful workaround as an answer)

Comment: BTW -- don't use backticks for command substitution. That's an artifact of the 1970s -- the modern `$( )` command substitution syntax has been POSIX-standardized since the beginning of the 90s, and is generally much better-behaved (nests properly, doesn't change behavior of backticks within, etc).

Comment: (err, I should have said "doesn't change behavior of _backslashes_ within" above)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does cd in backticks never work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033910/why-does-cd-in-backticks-never-work)

Comment: @Aserre the OP is trying to capture the error message **if one is produced**, e.g. by `cd /dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton for explaining my question. I need to change directory in my script and proceed if successful and capture the error message in a variable if not. **I did not know that $() or back tick forked a separate process**.

Perhaps I can re-direct stderr to a temp file and read from it or is there a direct method.

checking for the existence of the directory before changing to it is an option but will it work if the script does not have the permission?

Comment: I'd just do what @CharlesDuffy suggests, he's invariably correct about all things bash.

Comment: @SeniorCoder, yes, redirecting to a temporary file will work; I prefer the run-`cd`-twice approach insofar as the error case is rare so it makes sense to optimize to make the common case fast, but if you'd rather create a temporary file and set up the redirection every time, no reason you can't.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't general to all commands -- it's specific to builtin commands that change the current shell's state, because `$( )` (or its older backtick equivalent) forks off a child process and runs the contained code there, not in the parent shell.

---

Putting `cd` in a wrapper that tries to run it again in a subshell with output captured might look like:

```
# wrapper sets a variable cdError with stderr content
cd() {
  local rc
  if builtin cd "$@"; then
    cdError=
    return
  else
    rc=$?
    cdError=$(builtin cd "$@" 2>&1)
    return "$rc"
  fi
}
```

...such that after an unsuccessful run of `cd`, you can find the associated error message captured in `"$cdError"`.

That said, I question why you're doing this at all. `cd /somewhere || exit` and letting errors go to stderr directly suffices for most common use cases.

Comment: @KurtisRader I just assumed they spoke Spanish :-)