# How to change directory in a Shell Script?

Tags: git, shell

This is my first time I create a Shell Script.

At the moment I'm working with nodejs and I am trying to create a Shell Script and use git in it.

### What my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site
```

This script is located at my desktop and it works (yes I have git installed).

### What I want

After it downloaded the git repository, I want to:

```
cd /site
npm install
```

I have Nodejs and NPM installed.

### What I tried

I just want to dive into the created folder and run the command `npm install` so I thought to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site
echo "cd /site"
echo "npm install"
```

Also I've read about the [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script) and I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site
alias proj="cd /site"
proj
echo "npm install"
```

But nothing works..

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: You probably mean `cd site` without the slash.

Comment: `echo` is for displaying text on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be simpler than you think (since you are writing bash (or whatever shell you use) 'scripts' all time, just by using the command line):

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site
cd site
npm install

cd - # back to the previous directory
```

To make it a bit more robust, only run `npm` if `cd site` succeeds (more on that in [Chaining commands together](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF)):

```
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site
cd site && npm install && cd -
```

---

Just because I read some article about [reliable bash](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/), here's yet another version:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDPWD=$(pwd)
git clone git://github.com/Tmeister/Nodejs---Boilerplate.git site \
    && cd site && npm install && cd "$OLDPWD"
function atexit() { cd "$OLDPWD"; }
trap atexit EXIT # go back to where we came from, however we exit
```

Comment: What is the point of cd'ing just before `exit`? What could be different if the script didn't?