# bash: script that allows user to change directory based on ouput from another program

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

**Background:**

This question is about using the cd command in a bash script or alias.

There is a related SO question here: [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414)

**Problem:**

Suppose you have a bash program called "foopath" that sends a path to a directory to stdout when you pass in an argument, e.g.,

```
  $> /usr/bin/foopath 1998      ## returns /some/long/path/here/1998
  $> /usr/bin/foopath 80817     ## returns /totally/different/path/80817/files
```

The foopath program just does a lookup and returns the closest matching path it can find based on the argument the user passed in.

**Question:**

1) How would you construct a function and alias in your .bash_profile so that the user can:

- 1a) type `foo 1998` or `foo 80817` (foopath command shortening goal)
- 1b) change dir using `cd foo 1998` or `cd foo 80817` (change-directory goal)
- 1c) change directory from the command prompt (not-just-subshell-only goal)

**Pitfalls**

Because of the goal in 1c above, this seemingly simple task is proving cumbersome. In other words, the function/alias should be usable interactively, just as shown in the example from the related SO post at [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414).

Comment: Please clarify 1c). Do you mean using the function/alias interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a)

```
foo () {
    cd "$(foopath $1)"
}
```

1b)

```
cd () {
    case $1 in     
      (foo) builtin cd "$(foopath $2)";;
      (*)   builtin cd "$@";;
    esac
}
```

1c) Both 1a) and 1b) can be used interactively.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be either

1. by making the script a function instead

   ```
   function script() 
   {
        cd "$(foopath "$*")"
   }
   ```
2. by using `source script.sh` (or `. script.sh`) instead, so the script runs in the calling shell