# Why is the final directory cmd of bash script not executing?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple bash script to create a new directory. The last line to cd into the $dir is not executing. If I change it to echo "Hello world" it works, if I change it to cd ../, it does not work. Everything else in the script is functioning as it should.

```
clear
read -p "Directory Name  : " name
echo "Creating a directory called " $name
cd ~/Sites
mkdir $name
cd $name
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script.

Comment: This question could be rephrased as "Why doesn't “cd” work in a bash shell script?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (I'm assuming) the line of code you wrote in your interactive shell to execute your script:

```
./FooScript.sh
```

Which is interpreted the exact same way as writing:

```
bash FooScript.sh
```

This causes your script to be executed in a subshell. Your subshell has its own concept of where it is in your file system. So, you changed the directory of the subshell to ~/Sites/$name directory, but not the directory of the interactive shell.

There are two ways you can fix your problem - try executing your script again in either one of two ways:

```
source FooScript.sh

. FooScript.sh
```

This way, your script runs inside the same process as your interactive shell, rather than inside a subshell as a new process.

Answer (score 1):

cd does work in the script but it does not affect the calling process, that is, the shell.

If you source the script with `. foo`, it should work.