# How to cd, then append to a file from inside a shell script?

Tags: shell, docker, graphite, cd

Here is a portion of my shell script:

```
...
docker exec -it graphite bash
cd /opt/graphite/conf
echo >> storage-schemas.conf
echo "[atlas]" >> storage-schemas.conf
echo "pattern = test.atlas" >> storage-schemas.conf
echo "retentions = 1s:15d,10s:45d" >> storage-schemas.conf
...
```

I want to bash into a running docker container (called graphite), 
then cd into /opt/graphite/conf 
then append a few lines of text to a file called storage-schemas.conf. 
But when I run the above shell script, it creates a new file storage-schemas.conf on my desktop (which is my working directory) and appends to that!

I know I'm not using cd command correctly as this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script) explains. But I really need my shell script to not have any dependency, as the end goal is to provide a one-click solution across many teams. Is there a way?

Comment: your cd/echo commands are running as part of the main bash script, and will only run AFTER the docker command has finished/exited. you need to put those cd/echos into their OWN shell script, and tell docker to execute it inside the container.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Marc! I too realized this that my shell script pauses after running the docker command, and only after I manually exit the docker container (type 'exit' then hit enter), does my remainder of shell script execute.
Now let me try to figure out how to tell docker to execute a shell script inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the work-around for this problem was fairly simple. Instead of entering inside the docker container and then trying to append a file, I'm now copying the file from host and pasting(overwriting) it inside the docker container. I can achieve this easily using the `docker cp` command and I don't have to leave my main bash script (Thanks again [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) for pointing this out).