# Starting fifo at the startup Linux fedora

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, fifo

I have been using fifos for controlling mpg123 player, there every-time I need to execute these 3 commands

```
mkfifo a // create fifo
cat > a & //to run it indefinately
mypid=$! //assign some dummy pid
```

I want to put this into some script which would execute it at the boot, i wrote a script containing these commands.
but it was not working, after some search i got i had to execute it like

```
. test.sh
```

manually i can execute it like the above way but automatically how to execute i am struggling.?

**EDITED**
*test.sh*
cd /root/work/

now executing this as ./test.sh will not change directory on terminal as it is executed in child process, and executing it as . test.sh will change the directory to /root/work.
I want to execute it as . test.sh through some function/script or anything that i can put at startup and at every boot it runs

Comment: have you tried `sh /full/path/to/test.sh` ?

Comment: do not put "sh" in front do "./full_path_to_script.sh" check if script executable

Comment: yeah, i tried manually i can execute the script like **. test.sh** but i want to execute it at the startup, there it is executing as **test.sh** please not . here.

Comment: @Noproblem script i can execute but i want to execute it as . test.sh at the startup but if i put this in /etc/init.d there it is executing as simply test.sh, without the . it is not sourcing and cat and mypid commands has no use.
For reference
[link](http://www.heapoverflow.me/question-please-help-me-make-this-bash-script-work-29618298)

Comment: @Dinesh chaudhary try "source /dir_to_script/test.sh " without dot.  What path to test.sh and file who's sourcing? From where do you call your script, and what command trying to do?

Comment: What is startup? system startup (`/etc/rc.local`), services startup (`/etc/init.d`), gdm/lightdm login (`~/.config/autostart`), bash login (`~/.bashrc`) or something else? My best guess is that you want one of the last 2 cases. It does not make much sense to run these commands at system startup... They could be per-user...

Comment: @Noproblem if i do **source /root/work/test/test.sh** it executing, but when i want to execute same by other script so i am having a script file _/root/work/test/test1.sh_
which contains 
**#!/bin/sh
source /root/work/test/test.sh**
But source at the start is not having any effects here the command is simply executing like **/root/work/test/test.sh**

Comment: @Dinesh chaudhary , so for the first run it's ok? but your other script can't execute? Maybe you should put in function? and call function from other scripts. If you can provide more information, and edit your quoestion

Comment: Check this link: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip

Comment: @Noproblem edited the question with more details.

Comment: @Dinesh chaudhary thanks for edit,  you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script  . At the end of your ~/.bashrc file add: source /root/work/test/test.sh

Comment: @Noproblem Now if I execute my script as **source /root/work/test/test.sh** perfectly fine but when putting the same line at the end of ~/.bashrc file it's not working same way

Comment: @Dinesh chaudhary , maybe ~/.bashrc belong to user - non root, and user can't execute files in /root path, or read it or cd to directory. What output of command `whoami`?

Comment: output is **root** only, cd is working there in ~/.bashrc but   
_mkfifo /root/work/test/a_  
_cat > /root/work/test/a &_  
_mypid=$!_  
this script doesn't work is it because of some specific commands or any other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mpg123 they are providing feature for fifo control of the player

instead of executing all the commands mentioned above

just
**mpg123 -R --fifo /usr/test/FIFO_NAME**

and then send the command to FIFO and it's done.