# How to use the Bash read command to capture filepaths containing "~" (tilde)

Tags: bash, tilde

So I've been starting bash scripting, and I'm making a script that will autoinstall from source (so essentially it just compiles tarballs for you). I need it to change directories in order to go to a tarball. However, whenever I use this command

```
read path
cd $path
```

I always get the error `tar-installer.sh: line 13: cd: ~: No such file or directory` 
For anyone needing it, here's the full script...

```
#!/bin/bash
# This program auto-installs tarballs for you.
# I designed this for Linux noobies who don't
# know how to install tarballs. Or, it's for
# people like me who are just lazy, and don't
# want to put in the commands ourselves.

echo "Tar Installer v1.1"
echo "Gnu GPL v2.1"
echo -n "Path to tarball:"
read path
cd $path
echo -n "Please enter the file you wish to complile..."
read file
if  $file =="*.tar.gz"
then
    tar -xzf $file
   else
       $file =="*.tgz"
then
    tar -xzf $file
else
    $file =="*.tar.bz2"
then
    tar -xjf $file
```

The final part with the tarballs is still a work in progress. But the directory I used for `cd path` was `~/Downloads/`

It's probably an easy fix, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Issue appears to be related the read built-in function when accepting filepaths with "~/" in it.

Comment: please use http://shellcheck.net and correct any errors found there before posting code  (You should do this now). Thanks and good luck..

Answer (score 6):

You need to replace the tilde `~` by the home path. This expansion fails if it is not performed directly.

```
 cd "${path/#~/$HOME}"
```

will replace `~` with your home directory using bash's replace `${value/search_term/replacement}`.

You may also want to combine echo & read:

```
read -p "Path to tarball: " pathname
```

Also be careful when naming variables like path (PATH is your environment variable)

Comment: How about the PATH `~other_user`?

Comment: If your directory layout is regular Linux standard, adding a second substitution to replace any remaining leading `~` with `/home/` would seem like an obvious approach.

Answer (score -2):

Because "cd" is build-in function of bash.
So you should try to run your script like this:

```
 #source tar-installer.sh
```

Similar issue here:

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Comment: No, this is not the problem reported.

Comment: Why ? I do not understand.
I tried to run exactly the script tar-installer.sh  in Ubuntu 14:04
The first time I had error with "cd", but then there isn't  error with  "source" .
So I think #source tar-installer.sh  will solve the problem.

Comment: The problem here is with tilde expansion. If `~` is already part of the variable, it will not get expanded. The question link you gave tackles a completely different problem. When you _execute_ a script as opposed to `source`ing it, a subshell is spawned. `cd` changes the working directory in that shell; working directory in parent remains unchanged. This behavior has nothing to do with the question asked here.

Comment: Also, you should not `source` something that you don't know. `source` can change current shell's environment. You should be extremely careful with that. If you are the author of the script & have taken proper precautions so as not to corrupt the existing environment with unintended side effects, then only you should source it.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.I got it. I'm still new here,I will be more careful before posting a reply (: