# "cd" command in git bash script not working

Tags: git, git-bash

I am relatively new to Git Bash. 
Given below is the script that I am trying to execute. I saved the given below 3 lines in a file sshExec and tried running it in Git Bash. The first two line ran as expected but 3rd line didn't run. There is no error or warning as well. So there was no directory change as I wished my script to do.

Why is it that "cd anyPath" is not working in script?

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add C:\\Users\\xyz\\.ssh\\id_rsa
cd D:/Repositories/RELEASE_2017_BugFixing/deltagen_teamlogic
```

Comment: Does that path actually exist on your system?

Comment: @Tim Yes. that path exists.

Comment: Are you expecting that the current working directory of your shell changes after running those lines in a separate script? How do you determine that the directory hasn't changed?

Comment: Yes the current working dir should change after the script finishes.  I am running command pwd to know about the current directory.

Comment: @tripleee..Thanks.You got it right...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2236614/1465553. solved the problem for me. I should have run it as ". ./sshExec" instead of "./sshExec".

Answer (score 1):

Both answers above are synthetically correct. Try verifying the path you are trying to access.

Alternatively, you can go to the project folder manually then right click and select `git bash` option. This will trigger `bash` terminal automatically; opening the intended directory.