# This simple bash script doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create the script that will simply do `cd ../` times `n`, where `n` is whatever I pass to it, or `1` by default:

```
STEPS=${1:-1}
for i in $STEPS; do
    cd ..
done
```

It doesn't give me any errors and it does nothing..

Comment: I ran your code and it did correctly put me up a single directory. The ${1:-1} is evaluated as 1.

Comment: So is it my computer then? :/ this is very strange.. Thanks!

Comment: I ran the code directly from a shell. You should try to see if that works. From a script, it will only do the cd command within the script not in your shell where you execute the script I believe.

Comment: Add debugging output, so you understand what/where is happening. I.e. `echo currDir=$PWD ; cd .. ; echo nowDir=$PWD` . Good luck.

Comment: The result should be either 1 or N (being a number I pass as a first argument). It evaluates correctly - meaning it sets 1 if I don't pass let's say 4 or 5. Then the for loop gets executed once, but it doesn't do `cd ..`. And yes, I want to create a sequence. So if `$STEPS` is 5, it should loop 5 times.

Comment: you probably meant to do `STEPS={1..n}`

Comment: Why do you expect `for i in 2` to run twice? It'll assign `2` to `i` and run the loop once, just as `for i in *` will run only once if you only have one file, even if that file's name is `2`.

Comment: I think you actually want a Bash *function* for this, if you want to invoke it in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, you generally don't want to generate a sequence of numbers to iterate over. Use the C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$STEPS; i++)); do
  cd ..
done
```

If this is in a file, you need to source it ( `. ./cd-up`) rather than executing it (`sh ./cd-up` or `./cd-up`, etc).

If you are, in fact, using `zsh`, you can simply use the `repeat` construct:

```
repeat $STEPS do cd ..; done
```

or its shorter form for simple commands

```
repeat $STEPS cd ..
```

Comment: God dammit! :D OK, the for loop works now, but `cd` doesn't work. I'm guessing it can't change the directory like this.. this is pain.

Comment: @Kernel.Panic, are you expecting your script to change the directory of its parent process (that is, the separate shell that's launching it)? Your code is fine, but you'll need to put it in-process with the shell whose directory you want to change. You can do that by putting it in a shell function, or *sourcing* in the script.

Comment: @Kernel.Panic I believe it can. Check to see if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39150500/5272567) can't help.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to source it to do what you wish, e.g.

`. yourscript.sh 3`

to change directory 3 times. (notice the dot before the `yourscript.sh`)

After you fix the script at least, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
STEPS=$1
for ((i=1; i<=$STEPS; i++)); do
  cd ..
done
```

Thanks @Charles Duffy for mentioning sourcing, and thanks @chepner for the fixed for loop.

Some info:

> Shell scripts are run inside a subshell, and each subshell has its own
>   concept of what the current directory is. The cd succeeds, but as soon
>   as the subshell exits, you're back in the interactive shell and
>   nothing ever changed there.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255415/5272567)

Comment: I followed this, but if I just `echo` from within the for loop, it works. I can see the output `n` times. However `cd` still does not work.  Btw, I'm using bash, because if I use `sh`, then it dumps an error - `Bad for loop variable`.

Comment: sh is a common extension for bash executable files. Did you make it executable with `chmod +x yourscript.sh`? I just ran this on a MATE desktop on my debian, and it did indeed move me back the directories.

Comment: what terminal are you using?

Comment: yes, I used `chmod +x` and btw, I just ran `cd /home` without anything else in the code, and it doesn't work. It might be my terminal then. I am using `zsh` and wondering if it has something to do with it.

Comment: are you making sure to source it and not run it? e.g. not `./script.sh 1` but instead `. script.sh 1`?

Comment: I think it actually is my `zsh`, because I just ran your version again and it closed the terminal window completely.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Because I was curious, I actually installed `zsh`, and it gives me the error `.: no such file or directory: script.sh` when I try to source the script. So yes you are right might very well be `zsh`.

Comment: Yep, it is `zsh` problem definitely, because I just ran the same exact code on a normal terminal and it works!

Thanks guys! I will probably accept this answer, as it has all the mentions of others' comments and if anyone stumbles upon this question, it would be much easier for them to find the answer.

Thanks guys!

Comment: if you didn't notice @chepner modified his answer and mentioned how you can do this with `zsh`. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$STEPS` is always a single number, then your `for` loop will only run for one iteration. This is because the type of loop that you're using expects a list of words:

```
for name in word1 word2 word3; do
    # some stuff
done
```

This will run three times, assigning each value in the list to variable `$name`.

Using a C-style loop, you could do this:

```
steps=${1:-1}
for (( i = 0; i < steps; ++i )); do
    cd ..
done
```

Alternatively, in any POSIX shell you can use a `while` loop:

```
steps=${1:-1}
while [ $steps -gt 0 ]; do
    cd ..
    steps=$(( steps - 1 ))
done
```

If you pass in something that's not an integer, then neither of these approaches will work!

---

Remember that if you run this as a script, it will change the directory while the script is running but the parent shell (the one you ran the script from) will be unaffected.