# Unable to 'cd' using my bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

I have an installation script running, and the last thing the script does is it runs `npm install` in my `testrepo` directory.

This is how my folders looks like:
[image]

The `testrepo` is a node project, containing the `package.json` file.

Now, as part of my `install.sh` script, I try to do the following:

```
 echo "Installing test repo node packages and dependencies...." &&
 cd testrepo/ && 
 npm install &&
 echo "Finished installing"
```

However, this does not seem to run the `npm install` in the `testrepo`, and still says in has finished installing.

What is a good work around to fix this issue?

> Note: The `install.sh` script has a lot of tasks to be done inside it.

Comment: please share the error you are getting in command line

Comment: What's with the `&&`s?!

Comment: Why do you think that "this does not seem to run the `npm install`"?

Comment: There is no error. im new bash scripting, and from reading online apparently you add && in order to wait for the command to finish before running the next one. It doesnt run the npm install because it cannot change directory from the script itself, thats why - hence looking for workaround...

Comment: @emisqwe, try this: `dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd); cd "$dir/testrepo && npm install"`

Comment: try doing `npm install --verbose` or `npm i --verbose`

Comment: @emisqwe No, no, no. Commands on separate lines will wait for the previous ones to finish per default. If you need to be sure that the previous command was *successful* then you can use `&&` but you *mustn't* put a newline after it. Or you can use `set -e` to get that behaviour (well, sort of) globally.

Comment: @Biffen so when do you use && ?

Comment: @emisqwe: `&&` is used mainly in command line

Comment: @emisqwe, it is the way to check the exit status of the previous command. It is a logical _AND_. If the return status is zero (success), the next command is executed. For other status codes (error), the next commands are ignored

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov same issue even with implementing your solution - this is the issue I think, just not sure how to solve it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: @Venkatraman I disagree. `&&` can be, and is, used *a lot* in scripts as well.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov it works great if I do it manually, but it has to be done within the install.sh script

Comment: @emisqwe Could you try removing all the `&&`s, adding `set -ex` at the top of the script (but below the shebang) and showing us the full script, the exact command you use to run it as well as the complete output?

Comment: @Biffen, you misunderstood my point. the given line is command level. `&&` in script is scripting level.

Comment: @Venkatraman I've absolutely no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Biffen, `&&` inside is an `operator` and has many usage

Comment: @Biffen There is no problem putting a newline after `&&`; a command cannot end with a `&&`, so the shell knows to read the next command from the next line.

Comment: @Venkatraman `&&` is often used in scripts, as Biffen said.

Comment: @chepner You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

With the && you create an expression. That is where it goes wrong.

As an example, if my current directory is /tmp, and I execute

```
(cd .. ; pwd ) && pwd
```

you can see what happens:

```
/
/tmp
```

Comment: im afraid even after removing the &&, the issue is still there

Comment: In the script without the `&&`s, try putting `pwd` in before and after your `npm install` (on a separate line). This is will show you what is hapening.